# Странные цифры в http ответе

Tags: post, http

После получения http ответа замечаю шестнадцатеричное число после заголовка, непосредственно перед контентом. И в конце - 0. То есть контент как бы заключен между этими цифрами. Что это за цифры?

Пример:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2011 10:36:25 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Unix) mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.8.8
Set-Cookie: *************************************************
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml

3380     <---------  Вот здесь непонятная цифра (взята произаольно)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<list>
    xml-текст
</list>
0        <--------- И здесь (всегда 0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это размеры чанков (частей) ответа в байтах, выраженные в шестнадцатиричном виде.

Т.к. HTTP требует наличия терминального (завершающего) чанка, то его размер равен 0. После 0, кстати, должен присутствовать перенос строки.

В вашем случае ответ состоит из двух чанков:

- xml-документ, размером в 0x3380 (13184) байт;
- терминальный пустой чанк.

Comment: Пару ссылок с подробным описанием:
[RFC 2616 HTTP/1.1 3.6.1 Chunked Transfer Coding][2]

[Chunked transfer encoding в wikipedia][1]


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding
  [2]: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.1

Comment: То есть ответ выдается как бы частями (Всеравно что длинное SMS)? Вобщем я все понял. Спасибо вам!

Answer (score -2):

Значение этих цифр вы можете узнать у автора веб-сервера (документация), или (что более вероятно) из документации по протоколу, по которому идет общение.