# Числа, цифры, хексы, буквы и другая каша в голове

Tags: терминология, системы-счисления, faq

> Сколько раз слово "и" встречается в букве "цивилизация"?

Никто же так не спрашивает - все понимают, где буквы, а где слова.
Так сколько же можно издеваться над числами, постоянно путая связанные с ними понятия?

Итак, как правильно использовать понятия, связанные с числами, и чем они отличаются?

Comment: Вообще-то, в школьной программе по арифметике говорится, что такое число, и что такое цифра.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, предлагаешь посылать спрашивающих сначала перечитать школьную программу?

Comment: Да, как-то до сих пор я считал, что у нас в стране обязательное среднее образование. Его отменили?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Иногда мне кажется, что да.

Comment: по-моему, вопрос следует перенести на [meta.ru.so].

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, а по-моему, ему тут самое место. Терминология всё-таки относится к тематике сайта, а не меты.

Comment: тогда вопрос, наверняка, следует переформулировать. чтобы на него можно было дать **ответ**. есть такое шуточное определение: риторический ответ — это ответ, не требующий вопроса. по-моему, у вас получились именно риторические ответы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, дописал нужный вопрос с вопрос :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, отлично! если бы ещё добавить про то, что подразумевается точный профессиональный контекст (ну, или как-то в этом духе), было бы вообще замечательно. (оговорка нужна ввиду того, что в более широком контексте слово «цифра» вполне может употребляться вместо слова «число»).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, [не может](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ntes/5472/ЦИФРА), помимо устойчивых оборотов типа "солидная цифра". Только в одном словаре видно значение "число", и то с пометкой "разговорное". Использовать слово "цифра" вместо "число" с точки зрения русского языка неверно.

Comment: *и то с пометкой "разговорное"* — вот это я и подразумевал. *Использовать слово "цифра" вместо "число" с точки зрения русского языка неверно* — я думаю, это следует обсуждать где-нибудь на http://rus.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, грань между разговорным и неграмотным очень тонкая. В общем, я не считаю правильным вносить это уточнение.

Comment: *грань между разговорным и неграмотным очень тонкая* — не спорю. все мы её время от времени переходим (пример:  [в **linux**'е тоже возможно создавать кастомные протоколы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453081/178576)), но на профессиональных сайтах, действительно, лучше пользоваться профессиональным сленгом.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Числа

Число - это абстрактная единица измерения количества.

`1`, `2`, `1888`, `712.4` - всё это числа.
`-7` - тоже число. Хотя в большинстве языков программирования литеральной записью не обладает.

Число представляет собой значение. Оно не обладает ни единицей измерения, ни системой счисления. Строго говоря, нельзя даже говорить, что оно состоит из цифр.

## Числа в рамках языка программирования

К тому, что сказано выше добавляется тип данных, а так же возможность литеральной записи.

В памяти число представлено неким набором бинарных данных. Не надо говорить, что в этом куске памяти лежат хексы. Это просто байты и биты. Шестнадцатеричный дамп куска памяти - это именно дамп, но не число.

Например, для Си:

- `10`, `012`, `0xa`, `0x0A` - это разные записи одного и то же числа.
- `10`, `10L`, `10.0` - это разные (хотя и равные) числа, поскольку они имеют разный тип данных. Конечно, они могут рассматриваться как одинаковые, если для нас важна величина, а не тип, но с точки зрения компилятора они различаются.

## Системы счисления

Число может быть представлено в виде строки в различных системах счисления.
Это по-прежнему одно и то же число, но строковые представления различны.

`"1111111111"`, `"1010"`, `"14"`, `"A"` - это всё представления числа 10 в различных системах счисления (унарная, бинарная, шестиричная и шестнадцатеричная соответственно).

Фраза "*число в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления*" корректна, но неявно подразумевает "*текстовое представление числа в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления*", т. е. речь далее идёт о строке, а не о числе.

## Цифры

Буква - это один символ в слове, а
Цифра - это один символ в строковом представлении числа (по умолчанию - десятичном).

Цифра может подразумевать и строковый (`"5"`, `"A"`), и числовой (`5`, `10`) вариант.
Строковый вариант представляет собой выводимый символ, тогда как числовой следует рассматривать как остаток в кольце вычетов.

Арифметические операции над цифрами в производить нельзя.
Фраза "сложить цифры 5 и 7" некорректна, складывать можно только числа.

Однако, в некоторых случаях возможна неявная интерпретация цифр как чисел.

## Цифры числа

Если не оговаривается система счисления, то подразумевается десятичная.

Под цифрами числа, как правило, подразумеваются числовой смысл цифр.
Т. е. цифры числа - это набор остатков в кольце вычетов по основанию системы счисления, который при скалярном умножении на соответствующие степени системы счисления (уже вне кольца) даст оригинальное число. По умолчанию этот набор упорядоченный.

В этом контексте можно говорить об арифметических операциях, например "*сумма цифр числа*" - это сумма чисел указанного выше набора. Поскольку речь уже идёт о числах, система счисления более не играет роли - она была нужна только для получения набора.

## Цифры в строковом контексте

Цифра - это любой символ, который относится к соответствующей категории юникода.
Можно считать, что он используется для записи чисел в естественных языках (языки программирования не подходят: в записи `0xA` - символ `A` используется как цифра, но в реальности является буквой). В то же время я не могу со стопроцентной гарантией сказать, что любая цифра юникода используется хотя бы в одном естественном языке.

PS: В большинстве случаев выше подразумеваются целые числа, однако аналогичная интерпретация возможна и для дробных.

Comment: Извините, но на трезвую голову я даже с третий попытки не могу осмыслить эту фразу "Под цифрами числа, как правило, подразумеваются числовой смысл цифр." Это что-то из философии не для простых смертных?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, там пунктом выше я написал про два смысла - числовой и текстовый. Например, есть число 19191 = 0x4AF7. Под его цифрами в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления в большинстве случаев будет пониматься набор чисел `{4, 10, 15, 7}`, а не набор символов `{'4', 'A', 'F', '7'}`. Именно это позволит посчитать сумму `4 + 10 + 15 + 7 = 36`, тогда как `'4' + 'A' + 'F' + '7'` логическим смыслом не обладает.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вы решили написать комикс? Лично меня рассмешила фраза "Скорее всего, можно думать, что он используется для записи чисел в естественных языках.":)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, в юникоде есть региональные цифры. А сочетание "скорее всего, можно думать, что" получилось в результате подбора фразы... Имелось в виду, что есть цифры и естественных языках, поэтому так можно рассматривать принадлежность символа к классу цифр - он используется в естественном языке для записи числа (язык программирования не подходит - 0xA - использование, но A - это буква, а не цифра). В то же время, я не могу стопроцентно исключить вероятность наличия в юниуоде цифр, которые ни одним естественным языком не используются, поэтому "скорее всего". Как улучшить фразу?

Comment: Спасибо, как говорят англо-саксы, вы сделали мой день!  Сегодня я узнал, что -7 - это  тоже число! Не скажите, когда мы приступим к изучению -8? Не хочу пропустить эту лекцию!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, в большинстве языков программирования запись `-7` - это не число, а применение унарного минуса к числу `7` - именно поэтому я выделил отрицательные числа явно.

Comment: Автору 5 баллов

Comment: @Qwertiy Ух-ты! Я что-то совсем запутался: то ли -7 - это число, то ли это не число. Это явно мне "не по зубам"!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, именно для этого там фраза "Хотя в большинстве языков программирования литеральной записью не обладает". Javascript - литеральная запись числа может использоваться для ключа в литеральной записи объекта: `x = { 12: 7 }` и `y = { 12.3: 7 }` - можно, а `z = { -12: 7 }` - нельзя (SyntaxError), потому что `-12` - это не литерал. Другие языки делают то же самое, только там это сложнее продемонстрировать.

Comment: "В памяти число представлено неким набором бинарных данных. Не надо говорить, что в этом куске памяти лежат хексы. Это просто байты и биты." Справедливости ради надо отметить что ВСЕ в памяти и на диске - байты. Дальше их можно интерпретировать как числа, как строки, как данные неводомого формата и даже как код. Причем даже одновременно.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, да, всё хранится в бинарном виде. Тут речь немного о другом. Конкретно в случае чисел нет альтернативной интерпритации - это число и это бинарные данные. Эти данные не интерпретируются как строка или как число в некой системе счисления (даже про двоичную утверждение спорно для чисел длиннее одного байта).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, а вот и для Си пример: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34724513/4928642

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, чем пятнадцатеричная система не угодила?

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну... Я просто всё время про 16 слышал и в тексте далее она только поминается... Конечно, существовать может любая система, но в данном случае, кмк, 16 будет к контексту лучше подходить)

Answer (score 8):

Как не надо использовать слово "цифры":

- [Странные цифры в http ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/19375/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-http-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5)
  Хороший вопрос про chunked encoding, но почему в заголовке цифры, а не числа?
- [Что означают цифры в строке формата?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/29364/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0)
  Ширина и точность в формате printf/scanf - это тоже числа.
- [Слова в цифры (один>1)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/225383/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD1)
  Цифры "десять" в неоговоренной системе счисления не бывает.
  На самом деле подразумевается преобразование числа прописью к числу
- [Как зашифровать слово в цифры?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/315794/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B)
  Ставим цифры в соответствие emeil'у - правда?
- [Assembler. Изменение HEX по ходу программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/452773/assembler-%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-hex-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B)
  В памяти по заданному адресу хранятся данные, а не hex.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, специально для тебя, а то ты оказывается веришь, что школьную программу все знают.