# Запуск приложения с помощью собственного протокола

Tags: c#, windows, .net, протоколы

На сетевом диске лежит приложение `abc.exe`.
Как написать протокол, чтобы такая команда `abc:\\param` запускала это приложение с параметром `param`?
Как пишется протокол?
Все ли пользователи, имеющие доступ к шаре смогут использовать такой протокол или требуется на каждой машине требуется выполнить еще что-то?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Протокол прописывается в реестре Windows.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\yourprotocolname]
@="URL:Direct Connect Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\yourprotocolname\Shell\Open\Command]
@="cmd /c echo %1 & pause"
```

Обращаю внимание, что в браузере можно создавать ссылки на такой протокол. И таким ссылкам можно настроить автоматическое выполнение без запроса.

Поэтому очень важно отнестись к обработке передаваемых параметров внимательно.
Например, определённый выше протокол с именем `yourprotocolname` представляет собой огромную дыру в безопасности, поскольку можно сделать что-то типа `yourprotocolname:text & format d:`

PS: Знаю, что в linux'е тоже возможно создавать кастомные протоколы, но не имею ни малейшего представления, как это делать.

Comment: Тогда получается, что перед тем как пользователь смог бы воспользоваться протоколом, этот протокол должен быть описан в его реестре, правильно я понял?

Comment: @VladislavVitalyev, да. Хотя допускаю, что это можно сделать как-то через групповые политики.