# Создание на сайте кнопки открытия приложения

Tags: javascript

Как создать кнопку с помощью js которая откроет нужный мне exe файл.
Оконное приложение. Если быть точнее проект на Delphi.
Если кому то не понятно, что то на подобие как телеграмм запускаетсяс сайта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что значит открыть? Выполнить программу? Или просто открыть оконное приложение?

Comment: @РамазанАлисханов, скриншот добавился.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Элементарно (только сначала пользователь должен установить запускаемое приложение, а оно прописать себе соответствующий протокол в реестре):

```html
<a href=steam://store/253030>Открыть страницу Race The Sun</a><br>
<a href=steam://run/253030>Играть в Race The Sun</a>
```

Comment: Не подскажите где искать информацию по поводу этого, а то я вечерок посидел, так ничего и не нашел.

Comment: @Vasabi, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453081/178988