# Преобразование байт в строку с их HEX-представлением

Tags: java

В процессе разработки приложения столкнулась с необходимостью конвертировать массив шестнадцатиричных бит в строку.

Пример строки бит:

```
Object[] pduArray = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
SmsMessage[] arr = new SmsMessage[pduArray.length];


arr[1] = 05F7A8000...
```

Использую конструкцию:

```
String string = new BigInteger(1, (byte[]) arr[1]).toString(16)
```

Но эта конструкция съедает ведущие нули и выводит
`5F7A8000....` вместо `05F7A8000....`

Comment: Тут посмотрите: http://stackoverflow.com/a/332101/3212712

Comment: "шестнадцатиричных бит" - это как? И 05F7A8000 на входе - это что? Строка, число?

Comment: Может быть сильно не напрягаться и "прибавлять" ведущий ноль к результирующей строке, если количество символов нечетное? Конечно это не решит такую проблему, как *00* в начале строки, но насколько вероятно, что такое может появиться.

Comment: @pavlofff рискну предположить что для leading zeroes в Java есть более красивые средства типа String.format("%02d", num);

Comment: Шестнадцатеричные биты в `Object[]`? [Сначала прочитай](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453059/178988)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Не всякая комбинация битов/байтов может быть представлена как строка
2. Представление битов в строку зависит от кодировки строки. Один и тот же байт может быть представлен разными символом - соглашение об этом как раз и называется кодировкой

Судя по всему речь идет об Android - там кодировка по умолчанию UTF-8. Преобразование массива байтов в строку делается так:

```
public static String byteArrayToString(byte[] buf)
{
    try
    {
        return new String(buf, ENCODING);
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

`ENCODING="UTF-8"` - для Android или же можно просто вызывать `new String(buf)` - тогда будет применяться кодировка по умолчанию.

**Update**

Если требуется записать байты строкой, то поможет такой методочек:

```
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] array)
{
    char[] val = new char[2*array.length];
    String hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        int b = array[i] & 0xff;
        val[2*i] = hex.charAt(b >>> 4);
        val[2*i + 1] = hex.charAt(b & 15);
    }
    return String.valueOf(val);
}
```

Comment: "Не всякая комбинация битов/байтов может быть представлена как строка" - смотря как представлять. Байты 0x00, 0x01, 0x02 представить в виде строки "000102", равно как и любые другие аналогичным образом.

Comment: Как я понял, тербуется не преобразовать байты в символы, а записать байты строкой: 0xFF -> "FF"

Comment: @pavlofff да, именно так, 0xFF нужно вывести как FF а допустим 0x70 как 70

Comment: @Nastya И единственная проблема в том, что 0x07 у вас преобразуется в "7", а не в "07"?

Comment: @Nastya - надо яснее выражаться - см. апдейт ответа

Comment: именно так, и это превращает `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x07 0xA1` в `7A1` а нужно получить `0007А1`

Comment: @Nastya а почему вы выкидываете два нулевых байта?

Comment: Вы правы, извиняюсь, сама уже запуталась :) `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x07` должно превратиться в `00000007`

Comment: @Nastya String.Format("%02X", arr[i]); - не подойдет?

Comment: `String hexstring = new String.Format("%02X", arr[1])` так?