# Почему метод tostring() сжирает впереди стоящий ноль?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть переменная `n` которая содержит число `n = 084746473827;`

Когда я использую функцию `tostring()`, то возвращается уже `84746473827` (то есть уже без `0`).

Почему так происходит?

И как можно число приводить к строке без его изменения (например, число у нас `084746473827`, а нужно чтоб вернулась строка `084746473827`) ?

Comment: потому что число на самом деле _84746473827_ С чего вы взяли что у него стоит `0`?

Comment: То есть нельзя сделать чтоб возвращалось с ноликом как на входе?

Comment: да, только руками. При этом вы должны знать какая должна быть конечная длина. Откуда вы берете число с `0`?

Comment: вообще мне приходит переменная  в которой 084746473827 - число. (проверял typeof); но ответ ниже решил проблему . Всем спасибо за разъяснение

Comment: в переменной не может быть _084746473827_ потому что, как вы сказали это число, и оно автоматически отбрасывает лидирующие нули

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У чисел не учитываются ведущие нули. Если вам нужно заполнить нулями до определенной ширины, можно сделать так:

```js
var num, str;
num = 84746473827;
str = (new Array(12).join('0') + num).slice(-12);
console.log(str);
```

Comment: еще как учитываются!

Comment: @Igor аргументы?

Comment: почитайте другие ответы

Comment: @Igor Давайте без загадок. Я уже почитал

Comment: "Ноль в начале "литерал" целого означает, что число записано в восьмеричной системе."

Comment: @Igor Где в моем ответе про литерал? Проверка на общее понимание терминологии 0x00d7 - где ведущие нули?

Comment: Я написал ответ, в который включил код с примером `var a = 017;`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64072/discussion-between-tutankhamun-and-igor).

Answer (score 1):

Всё неправильно :). Ноль в начале "литерал" целого означает, что число записано в восьмеричной системе.  Вам повезло, что в числе встречаются цифры больше семи.

```js
// 017 is treated as octal
var a = 017;
console.log("a - decimal toString", a.toString());
console.log("a - octal toString", a.toString(8));

// 018 is treated as decimal
var b = 018;
console.log("b - decimal toString", b.toString());
```

Comment: [в строгом режиме вообще упало бы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/480625/186999)