# Числа, начинающиеся с нуля, в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Набираю в консоли Google Chrome следующий пример (и получаю интересный результат):

```
for (num = 050; num <= 100; num = num + 1) {
    console.log(num);
}
```

Печать почему-то начинается от 40. Если ввести вместо этого `num = 50`, то от 50. В чем разница этих значений для JavaScript, и почему цикл начинается с 40 в первом случае?

Comment: И вроде бы `08` должно быть ошибкой, разве нет?

Comment: @Grundy: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%C2%A0integer ? (хм, не скроллируется)

Comment: @VladD, если в числе цифры больше 7 - то считается обычным десятичным числом и ведущий ноль просто отбрасывается

Comment: @Grundy: Согласно [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB_integer): «Десятичный целочисленный литерал состоит из последовательности цифр без ведущего нуля.» Так что интерпретация 08 как 8 — это, судя по всему, самодеятельность конкретного браузера.

Comment: @VladD: [_Octal number syntax uses a leading zero. If the digits after the 0 are outside the range 0 through 7, the number will be interpreted as a decimal number._](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#Octal_numbers)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Числа, начинающиеся с нуля, считаются восьмеричными, если в них нет цифр больше 7.
[Ссылка на справку](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)

Грамматику можно посмотреть в спецификации: [11.8.3 Numeric Literals](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-literals-numeric-literals)

Comment: @ЖеняВеденин, на самом деле нормальный вопрос по не вполне очевидной особенности

Answer (score 7):

В JavaScript определяется целочисленный восьмиричный литерал следующим образом

```
OctalIntegerLiteral ::
       0o OctalDigits 
       0O OctalDigits
OctalDigits ::
       OctalDigit 
       OctalDigits OctalDigit
OctalDigit :: one of
       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Как можно видеть, литералы, начинающиеся с цифры 0, за которой следует буква строчная `o` или заглавная `O`, являются целочисленными восьмиричными литералами.

Проблема в том, что, например, мне не удалось использовать этот литерал в IE 11 независимо от выбранного режима ("USE STRICT").:) В то время как в FireFox 42 данный литерал успешно обрабатывается.

Также в JavaScript определяется так называемый `LegacyOctalIntegerLiteral`

```
LegacyOctalIntegerLiteral ::
        0 OctalDigit 
        LegacyOctalIntegerLiteral OctalDigit
```

В вашем случае используется именно этот литерал.

В спецификации EcmaScript (6 редакция) есть замечание, что

> A conforming implementation, when processing strict mode code (see
>   10.2.1), must not extend, as described in B.1.1, the syntax of NumericLiteral
>   to include LegacyOctalIntegerLiteral, nor extend the syntax of 
>   DecimalIntegerLiteral to include NonOctalDecimalIntegerLiteral.

Однако, как обычно, каждый браузер идет своим путем.:)

Comment: не _первым символом `O`_,  а `0o` или `0O`, то есть, вот это: `0o10` восьмиричное число, а вот это `o10` может быть обычной переменной, и если она не объявлена, будет _Uncaught ReferenceError: o10 is not defined(…)_

Comment: @Grundy Это я отвлекся и не туда посмотрел, когда писал текст.:)

Comment: а где кстати грамматику смотрели? :)

Comment: @Grundy Я смотрю ECMA-262. Я отвлекся ранее потому, что почему-то в IE 11 восьмиричный литерал не воспринимается независимо от выбранного режима.:)

Comment: ага, я в свой ответ добавил ссылку на спецификацию, кстати, как я понял в Edge они починили и этот литерал нормально работает :)