# Почему число начинающееся с 0 дает странный результат?

Tags: javascript

Игрался в консоли и заметил такую ситуацию:
если задать значение переменной любым числом (1, 47, -24.1), то в переменную сохранится это число, но если ей присвоить число, вида 010, 015 и т.п., то в переменную сохраняется значение 8, 13. Что здесь происходит и как это называется?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что это взято как воcьмибитное число (8), так как эта цифра имеет 0 в начале. Таким образом, соответствующее десятичное значение равно 10  |  012: (2 * 8 ^ 0 + 1 * 8 ^ 1 = 10)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480625/Числа-начинающиеся-с-нуля-в-javascript#480628

Comment: @Netahaki не "восмибитное", а "восьмеричное"

Comment: Джаваскрипт мэджик ^.^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ES5, чтобы представить восьмеричный литерал, вы используете нулевой префикс (0), за которым следует последовательность восьмеричных цифр (от 0 до 7). См. Следующий пример:

```
var a = 051;
console.log(a); // 41
```

Если восьмеричный литерал содержит число, выходящее за пределы допустимого диапазона, JavaScript игнорирует ведущее значение 0 и обрабатывает восьмеричный литерал как десятичный знак, как показано в следующем примере:

```
var b = 058; // invalid octal
console.log(b); // 58
```

[Подробнее](http://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/octal-and-binary-literals/)