# Что является "вторым максимумом" в задаче?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Здравствуйте!

[Источник задачи](http://pythontutor.ru/lessons/while/problems/seq_second_max/).

Условие:

> Последовательность состоит из различных натуральных чисел и
>   завершается числом 0. Определите значение второго по величине элемента
>   в этой последовательности. Гарантируется, что в последовательности
>   есть хотя бы два элемента.

Моё решение:

```
old = int(input())
k=1
i = int(input())
while(i != 0):
    if(i>old):
        print(i)
        k+=1
        break
    else:
        old = i
        i = int(input())
if(k!=2):
    print(old)
```

*Пояснение:*

Допускаю, что цифра 0 может быть только в конце списка, поэтому проверку на ноль исключил. Как я понял, второй максимум - это вторая по величине цифра. Т.е. первая цифра всегда является первым максимумом, а второй максимум - любая цифра, превосходящая первый максимум. Однако, примеры с указанного выше сайта утверждают обратное.

Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём я ошибаюсь и как решить тогда задачу?

Спасибо.

Comment: думаю, в своем пояснении Вы ошибаетесь. Максимум (у Вас - первый максимум) - это самое большое число в массиве (нет других 'вторых' максимумов, которые были бы больше). Задача, думаю в том (как написано в первом абзаце Вашего вопроса) - найти следующее по величине число (т.е. такое которое станет максимальным, если убрать первое). Однако тогда непонятны картинки, которые вы приводите. Там число 2 - это второе по величине во всех случаях, но почемуто помечены как ошибка.

Comment: думаю, на том сайте прикалываются

Comment: я думаю что там написан ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ответ а не ваш ответ, при запуске на 2 тесте у вас ответ 3.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы прочитать набор целых чисел — одно число на строку — пока не встретится ноль и найти в нём число, следующее за максимумом:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import heapq

_, second_largest = heapq.nlargest(2, iter(lambda: int(input()), 0))
```

Если последовательность чисел отсортирована по убыванию, то первое число является максимумом (наибольшее число), за ним следует второе по величине число (по условию: все входные числа различны).

[`heapq.nlargest(2, numbers)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html?highlight=heapq#heapq.nlargest) эквивалентно: 
`sorted(numbers, reverse=True)[:2]`, но может быть более эффективно, так как не требует загрузки всех строк одновременно.

---

Очевидно, что ответ не зависит от порядка чисел. Поэтому правильный ответ всегда `2` в вашем примере, в каком бы порядке набор чисел `{1, 2, 3}` не вводился бы. [Ваш код может вернуть `3`](http://ideone.com/e6Zvoz), что не верно. [Картинка вводит в заблуждение](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOPQv.jpg): она показывает правильный ответ *«`2`»*, но может говорить *«Неверный ответ :(»*.

Answer (score 3):

Наивно, не оптимально, работает.

```
first = int(input())
i = int(input())
if i > first:
    second,first = first,i
i = int(input())
while (i!=0):
    if i > first:
        second,first=first,i
    elif second<i<first:
        second=i
    i = int(input())
print(second)
```

Comment: мелкие придирки: 1- скобки вокруг условия в Питоне не нужны. Можно использовать `while i != 0:` или даже `while i:` вместо `while (i!=0):`. 2- в данном случае, достаточно условие `second < i` вместо `second < i < first`.  3- Если вы `int(input())` в нескольких местах повторяете, то можно функцию определить, например: `next_number = lambda: int(input())`. 4- возможно это дело вкуса, но имя `i` можно переименовать в `n` (`number`), чтобы избежать вводящих в заблуждение ассоциаций с индексом цикла. Для полной ясности, можно использовать `max_` и  `second_largest` имена.

Comment: у меня вопрос, почему в цикле while, идет переназначение переменных second,first=first,i, а не наоборот. я попробовал если сделать наоборот то работать не будет. но почему? 2-й вопрос: если после elif Второй меняется на И-тое, оно не перепишется при следующем input()?

Answer (score 2):

Я, например, воспринимаю "второй по величине", как второй по порядку при сортировке по убыванию.

Например, в 1 2 5 22 57 31 49
первый по величине - 57, а второй - 49.

Answer (score 2):

С помощью списка

```
i = int(input())
a = []
while i != 0:
    a.append(i)
    i = int(input())
a = sorted(a)
print(a[-2])
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Answer (score 1):

```
b = int(input())
max1 = b
a = int(input())
max2 = a
if max1 < max2:
    d = max1
    max1 = max2
    max2 = d
while a != 0:
    a = int(input())
    if max1 < a:
        max2 = max1
        max1 = a
    elif max2 < a <= max1:
        max2 = a
print(max2)
```

Рабочий код)

Comment: Это нет Пытоновой подход для размена переменных - вместо `d = max1; max1 = max2; max2 = d` используйте просто `max1, max2 = max2, max1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def second_max(array: [int, ]) -> int:
    first, second, *_array = array
    if not second:  # or not _array
        return second
    if first < second:
        first, second = second, first
    for current in _array:
        if current > first:
            second, first = first, current
        elif first > current > second:
            second = current  # значение второго по величине элемента
    return second

import random    
array = [random.randrange(10) for _ in range(random.randrange(1, 10))] + [0]  # состоит из различных натуральных чисел и завершается числом 0.
# array = [int(input())]
# while array[-1]: array.append(int(input()))
print(array)

print(second_max(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
max1 = 0
max2 = 0

while n != 0:
    if max1 <= n and max2 != n:
        max2 = max1
        max1 = n
    elif max2 <= n:
        max2 = n
    n = int(input())
print(max2)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

Вот этот код точно рабочий, предыдущие фрагменты не отрабатывают короткую последовательность 1,2,0.

```
max1 = int(input())
tmp = int(input())

max2 = tmp

while tmp != 0:
    if tmp >= max1:
        max2, max1 = max1, tmp
    elif max2 < tmp <= max1:
        max2 = tmp
    tmp = int(input())

print(max2)
```