# Второй максимальный элемент списка

Tags: python, list

Мне необходимо найти два максимальных элемента списка. С первым все просто. Для поиска второго элемента существует функция?

Или необходимо писать код, в котором я удаляю первый максимальный элемент и ищу максимум в оставшихся?

Это выглядит достаточно сложно, а если мне надо три максимума найти?? В общем, интересует простое решение. Спасибо.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Что является “вторым максимумом” в задаче?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/509517/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Можно отсортировать список и достать первые элементы:

```
items = [1, 3, 8, 2, 5]
items.sort(reverse=True)

print(items)
# [8, 5, 3, 2, 1]

print(items[:2])
# [8, 5]
```