# Почему число, созданное путем соединения элементов массива байтов, имеет неодинаковое значение в разных системах счисления?

Tags: математика, информатика

Не хватает мне какого-то фундаментального понимания, поэтому не ругайтесь на вопрос.
Итак, имеем массив байтов (восьмиразрядных двоичных чисел), пусть всего два элемента в нем:
00000001 , 00000001 
Допустим, наша цель получить какое-то большое число, пропуская байты через хеш-функции, вот мы и получили такой результат.
Ок, теперь просто эти значения выпишем в ряд , получив итоговое большое число:
100000001 (убраны нули первого байта).
В десятичной системе данное число равно 257.
Но, если мы изначально будем понимать наши байты как десятичные числа (две единицы), то соединенное аналогичным образом (уже) **десятичное** число 001001 (по три цифры на байт) ведь совершенно не равно 257. 
Вопрос возник после чтения инфы о биткоин ключах. По сути, HEX-число 17ab (два первых байта ключа) не эквивалентно  двоичному представлению 1011110101011 (эти же два байта) **если рассматривать эти два байта именно как единое число**.
В общем, я что-то запутался)

Comment: А Вы и не рассматривайте их как единое целое. Например 5+7=12, а если рассматривать их как "единое целое", то 5 и 7 равно 57, а 57 не равно 12. Вот и вся кухня.

Comment: "по три цифры на байт" - с чего бы это? Запишите одним байтом 666. Ну и неплохо было показать где же 17ab != 1011110101011b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с конца вашего вопроса. Последние 2 числа (17ab в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления и 1011110101011 в двоичной системе счисления) равны между собой. Можете проверить [здесь](http://calculatori.ru/perevod-chisel.html).

Думаю, вам будет полезно освежить в памяти информацию о позиционных системах счисления. См. [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Если кратко, то суть в следующем:

Пусть b - основание системы счисления (СС). b = 2 в двоичной СС, 10 - в десятичной, ... Цифры в СС всегда меньше ее основания (0 и 1 в двоичной СС, 0, 1, ..., 9 в десятичной СС, 0, 1, ...9, A, B, C, D, E, F в шестнадцатеричной). То, какую величину представляет каждая цифра в записи числа определяется ее позицией. В двоичной записи 10000001 первая единица дает `1*2^7=128` в десятичной системе, а вторая единица дает всего лишь 1.
Часто, когда работают с недесятичными СС вручную, в качестве промежуточной СС используют привычную десятичную СС.

Число из вашего вопроса 100000001, полученное склеиванием двух единиц, переводится в десятичную СС по формуле:
`1*2^8 + 0*2^7 + 0*2^6 +...+ 0*2^1 + 1*2^0 = 1*256 + 1`. 
То есть из-за своего положения первая единица превратилась в 256.
Если бы мы отпустили для каждой единицы не по 8 цифр, а, скажем, по 4, то у нас бы получилось: `1*2^4 + 1*2^0 = 1*16 + 1 = 17`. Видим, что значение, вносимое первой единицей, существенно изменилось бы.
Когда вы работаете с десятичными числами, вы берете с потолка решение отпустить под их запись по 3 цифры, и получаете `1*10^3 + 1*10^0 = 1*1000 + 1 = 1001`. Мне кажется, совершенно нечему удивляться, что ответы не совпали.

То, что упомянутые выше 2 числа (17ab в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления и 1011110101011 в двоичной системе счисления) можно разъединять-склеивать, и они остаются совпадающими вызвано тем, что основание одной системы (16) является степенью основания другой системы (2), то есть `16 = 2^4`, что приводит к тому, что 4 цифры из двоичной системы = 1 цифре из шестнадцатеричной. У двоичной и десятичной систем счисления нет такого счастливого свойства.

Comment: "По сути, HEX-число 17ab (два первых байта ключа) не эквивалентно двоичному представлению 1011110101011 (эти же два байта) **если рассматривать эти два байта именно как единое число**." автор вопроса даже выделил при каком условии эти числа не равны между собой.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  Я сейчас генерировал Bitcoin-адреса (это 32-байтовые числа, именно склеенные из некоего массива байтов) и сравнивал их в hex и двоичных системах. Действительно, к моему удивлению, взятые произвольно байты (точнее числа, получающиеся из них) совпадали друг с другом в разных системах, чего не было при сравнении с десятичной. Сейчас приходит понимание.

Comment: Точнее это не адреса, а приватные ключи, но не суть

Comment: @A_Mergasov Не за что. Спасибо за хороший вопрос. Ответ на него прояснил и для меня связь двоичной и шестнадцатеричной систем счисления)) Очевидно, так же связаны друг с другом двоичная и "четырехричная" СС, "четырехричная" и шестнадцатеричная СС. В общем, весь фокус в том, чтобы основание одной СС было степенью другой СС.

Answer (score 2):

Вот отсюда начинаются непозволительные операции:

> Но, если мы изначально будем понимать наши байты как десятичные числа
>   (две единицы), то соединенное аналогичным образом (уже) десятичное
>   число 001001 (по три цифры на байт) ведь совершенно не равно 257.

Двоичное представление числа - это одно, а десятичное представление числа - это другое. Как пример, "взаимозаменяемыми" являются два числа 0 и 1, остальные же числа имеют различное представления, поэтому применение такого "преобразования" ожидаемых результатов не даст.

```
0 | 000
1 | 001
--|----
2 | 010
3 | 011
4 | 100
...
```

Ответ ищите в позиционировании цифры в представлении числа. Например числа 5 и 7 в десятичной системе счисления представляют собой непосредственно 5 и 7, и их сумма (арифметическое "соединение") будет равна 12. Если же мы будем применять к ним операцию "соединения", которая подразумевается в вопросе, то таким образом получим число 57. А в числе 57, 5 указывает на количество десятков, а 7 на количество единиц, т.е. 5 чудесным образом стало 50 при "соединении", что есть бессмыслица.

И напоследок пример из естественных языков русского и грузинского: того, кого у нас называют "папа", по-грузински будут называть "мама" (гр. მამა - папа), а "мама" у нас не "папа". Поэтому не применяйте непозволительные преобразования для данных, на которых эти операции не будут иметь смысла.

Answer (score 0):

[Числа, цифры, хексы, буквы и другая каша в голове](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453059/178988)

Числа не обладают операцией конкатенации. Только строки.

Так уж вышло, что числа представлены в памяти как последовательность байт. И эта последовательность в чём-то похожа на конкатенацию. Но даже она ей не является - порядок байт даёт два варианта - little indian и big indian. Только в одном из них можно говорить о получении осмысленного результата после конкатенации.

Итак.
У тебя два байта со значением 1.
Что такое конкатенация - эта последовательная запись *цифр*.
Что здесь цифра? Сам байт.
Сколько возможных значений у байта? 256. Это основание системы счисления.
Получилось 11 в системе счисления по основанию 256.
Переводим в десятичную: 1*256+1 = 257. Сошлось.