# Сравнения чисел в разных системах числения

Tags: алгоритм, системы-счисления

Есть задание

> `Сравнить два n-разрядных чисел в системе счисления с основанием p (1=<n=<100, 2=<p=<16)`

Как я понимаю общий алгоритм такой:

1. Ввод чисел.
2. Конвертация их в общую систему.
3. Сравнения.
4. Вывод результата пользователю.

Но проблема именно в конвертации, как ее выполнять, написать алгоритм для каждой из систем - 2,8, 10, 16 ? Или есть более универсальный способ ? И что выводить если выбрана 6 система ?

Comment: Нет понятия «конвертация числа из одной системы в другую», есть лишь «разбор строкового представления»[.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453059/10105) И да, универсальный способ есть, разумеется. Вы ведь не думаете, что алгоритм разбора 17-ичной записи отличается от алгоритма разбора 19-ичной?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по той формулировке задания, которую вы привели, числа уже находятся в одной системе - с основанием p.
Более того, они имеют одинаковое количество разрядов - n.

То есть всё сводится к тому, что мы сравнивает цифру в первом разряде. Если она отличается - больше то число, у которого первая цифра больше.
Если одинакова - сравниваем вторую цифру. Если и она одинакова - то третью и так далее, пока не исчерпаем все цифры.