# c# String hex в int hex

Tags: c#

Есть строка

```
string a = "0x1234";
```

нужно конвертировать в

```
int a = 0x1234
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете использовать метод [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1k20k614(v=vs.110).aspx) с указанием основания системы счисления:

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(a, 16);
```

Comment: В этом случае i = 4660, а мне надо i = 0x1234

Comment: @Anastasia это одно и то же число. В десятичной системе счисления оно равно `4660`, в шестнадцатеричной - `0x1234`.

Comment: я знаю, но мне нужно побитово его сравнить с маской поэтому мне нужно чтоб но было в таком представлении 0x1234 и типа int.

Comment: @Anastasia вы без сомнения можете сравнивать его с маской. Я повторю еще раз: это *то же самое* число. Вы понимаете, что тип `int` хранит только число? Не его формат представления, а само число? А вот вывести на экран это число вы можете в любом виде: хоть в 10-м, хоть в 16-м, хоть в двоичном.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453059/10105

Comment: Теперь понимаю, спасибо. Для моей задачи это подходит.Ради интереса если б мне все таки нужно было чтоб оно было в формате int a =0x1234. как это можно сделать?

Comment: @Anastasia Для вывода чисел в 16-ном формате укажите для него формат `"X"`, например: `Console.WriteLine("{0:X}", i);`. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)