# Не могу перевести букву в номер ее кодировки

Tags: java, строки, символы

Делаю программу шифрования, не серьезную, так, чтобы себя развлечь. И столкнулся с этой проблемой: нужно как-то перевести строку в одно большое число в двоичной СИ. Прошу вас помочь мне=)

Comment: В смысле в двоичной? Вам нужно получить коды каждого символа, перевести их в 2сс и соединить в одну длинную строку из 0 и 1?

Comment: Приведите небольшой пример - так было, а так стало.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453059/10105

Comment: @0xdb, ему надо рассматривать входную строку (или блок) как одно N-байтное беззнаковое число.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот небольшой пример, который решает ваш вопрос.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String string = "Hello";//Исходная строка
    System.out.println(string);//Выводим строку

    byte[] arr =string.getBytes("UTF-8");//Преобразовываем строку в массив byte
    System.out.println(bytesToBin(arr));//Выводи массив byte в двоичном виде

    string = new String(arr, "UTF-8");//Получаем обратно строку из массива byte
    System.out.println(string);//Выводим полученную строку
}
/*
 * Переводим byte в строку с двоичным видом
 */
public static String byteToBin(byte b){
    return String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
}
/*
 *  Переводим массив byte в строку с двоичным видом
 */
public static String bytesToBin(byte[] bytes){
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(byte b:bytes){
        stringBuilder.append(byteToBin(b)).append(" ");
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет, мне это довольно сильно помогло, да и вообще прибавило знаний. Но у меня возникает ошибка в коде [https://github.com/DarkLadder/Encryption/blob/master/src/Window.java ](at Window$Action.actionPerformed(Window.java:54))

Comment: Так это не степень, это исключающее или, XOR

Comment: Да, не заметил. У вас java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Длина массива k 3, а вы пытаетесь обратиться к большему индексу.

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил

Answer (score 0):

самое простое - `Biginteger bigint = new Biginteger("string".toBytes());`

и обратно - `String str = new String(bigint.getByteArray());`