# строка в массив байтов

Tags: c#

У меня есть строка

```
string = "Hello";
```

Задача такова:

1. Надо преобразовать каждую букву в код ASCII(пример: H - 72, e - 101 и т.д.)
2. Полученные цифры перевести в двоичную систему счисления(пример: 72 - это 0b1001000)
3. Записать двоичный код в массив. Причём, индексы букв и их двоичные представления должны быть одинаковы(если H - первая буква, то и её двоичное представление должно быть первым в массиве).

Comment: Где ваши наработки? За вас делать задание никто не будет

Comment: Задавайте конкретный вопрос. Ваше задание за вас никто делать не будет.

Comment: ASCII-коды (0-127) во всех кодировках идентичны, т.е. содержат одни и те же символы. Для кодов 128+ размещение символов зависит от выбранной кодировки, но они и не входят в ASCII. Так что для перевода в числа достаточно явно привести `char` к `int`, например так: `int code = (int)'H'` в code будет значение 72. Дальше думайте сами, или приведите код вашей попытки и/или объясните что именно не получилось.

Comment: @Nikita сделали задание

Comment: Мне кажется, у вас какая-то [путаница в понятиях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453059/10105). У чисел нет системы счисления. Подумайте об этом.

Answer (score 3):

держи код, может быть он тебе жизненно необходим, в BinaryArray все как и просил

```
string s = "Hello!";
var ASCIIBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
var BinaryArray = new string[s.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) {
   BinaryArray[i] = Convert.ToString(ASCIIBytes[i], 2);
}
```