# Преобразовать число в массив из 4 байтов такого вида - {0x00, 0x00, 0x2F, 0xA3}

Tags: c#

Нужно преобразовать из числа массив из 4 елементов такого вида
byte[] qwe = {0x00, 0x00, 0x2F, 0xA3};
Пока-что остановился на

```
byte[] b1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(hash_ball); // {00, 00, 32, 64}
string B_2 = BitConverter.ToString(b1); // 00-00-14-40
```

Не могу преобразовать из этой строки массив, да при том что бы перед каждым елементом 0x стояло.

Answer (score 2):

Вы [путаете байт с его строковым представлением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453059/10105) в шестнадцатиричной системе.

Первый метод правильный. Полученный массив совпадает с тем, что вам нужно. Просто вы выводите его в десятичной системе счисления, а не в шестнадцатеричной.

Используйте для вывода

```
Console.WriteLine("{" + string.Join(", ", qwe.Select(b => $"0x{b:X2}")) + "}");
```

Comment: спасибо, но мне нужен не для вывода, а для записи в массив byte[]

Comment: @qweqwe: А для записи в массив подходит первый метод: `BitConverter.GetBytes`.

Comment: И как это будет выглядеть в коде, я просто не понимаю

Comment: @qweqwe: Вот так и будет выглядеть: `byte[] b1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(hash_ball);`.