# В чем измеряется хеш в c# и как получить хеш строки?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

В чем измеряется хеш в c#  и как получить хеш строки?
В чем имеено в битах? байтах?

Comment: Хеш — это число. Используйте `.GetHashCode()`.

Comment: @VladD в чем он выходит в байтах или битах(мне просто нужно получить 4 байтовое число)

Comment: Выходит `int`, это именно четырёхбайтовое число.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Хэш - это не результат измерения строки "в байтах или битах". Т.е. это не "длина в битах" и не "толщина в битах". Это не мера. Это просто какое-то число, которое одинаковое у одинаковых строк (не не обязательно разное у разных строк!). У огромной строки в миллион символов хэш вполне может быть равен 4.

Как получить хэш строки - так же, как и для любого объекта:

```
int hash = somestring.GetHashCode();
```

Не совсем уверен чем "в байтах" отличается от "в битах" - но в результате у вас будет хэш длиной в 4 байта. Они же - 32 бита.