# Получить DateTime в формате ISO 8601

Tags: c#

Не думал что задам такой вопрос, но я действительно не могу найти решение отформатировать текущую дату в ISO 8601, **отставив тип данных DateTime**

Вот мой код:

```
var datenow = DateTime.Now.ToString("o");
var dateTime2 = DateTime.Parse(datenow);
```

1 - Разве нельзя сразу вывести DateTime в нужном формате, не переводя его в строку??

2 - Даже если этот вариант самый лучший (туда сюда :) ) `DateTime.Parse` снова возвращает прежний формат.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988. И с датами так же.

Answer (score 5):

Вы путаете `DateTime` и его строковое представление. Возьмите, например, число 11 — оно может быть записано как 0xB, 013 или там XI, но оно тем не менее всегда остаётся числом.

Сам по себе объект типа `DateTime` форматом вывода не обладает, это просто объект с полями и методами. То, что вы видите — строковое представление, и да, при выводе объект превращается в строку, либо явно (тогда вы контролируете формат), либо неявно (тогда формат от вас не зависит).

Поэтому то, что вы видите как «значение `DateTime`» — это есть лишь его строковое представление, одно из возможных. `DateTime.Parse` лишь превращает форматированную строку назад в `DateTime`.

Ответ на ваш вопрос отрицательный: `DateTime` не обладает форматом, и вывести его и правда можно только превратив в строку (либо с указанием формата, либо без).

Как и любой другой тип, кстати[.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453059/10105)

---

Правильный вариант для преобразования между строкой и `DateTime` в обе стороны такой:

```
var lang = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; // или CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                         // смотря по тому, что вам нужно
var format = "o";
var dt = DateTime.Now;
var s = dt.ToString(format, lang);
var dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(s, format, lang);
```

Comment: Ну хорошо, как отформатированную строку, в тип DateTime превратить, не изменяя формат?

Comment: @Aleman: Формат _чего_? У `DateTime` формата нет.

Comment: Даты, которую я получил.

Comment: @Aleman: Давайте ещё раз. Объект `DateTime` **не обладает форматом**. Он не знает, с какой форматной строкой его будут выводить. Формат бывает только при превращении в строку.

Comment: Я уже с этим согласился. Сейчас у меня на руках строка. Как из неё сделать DateTime

Comment: @Aleman: `DateTime.ParseExact`?

Comment: Как я говорил, DateTime.ParseExact обратно переводит в прежний формат, и аргумент с форматом на него не действует: https://dotnetfiddle.net/atsopN

Comment: @Aleman: А что в вашем примере необычного? Всё как я и писал. У `dt2` **нет** внутри формата вывода. Что вы ожидали вместо этого?

Comment: @Aleman, `DateTime.ParseExact обратно переводит в прежний формат`  — `DateTime` является, грубо говоря, всего лишь числом. В каком именно формате вы его будете печатать, вы решаете непосредственно при этой печати, задавая соответствующую *локаль* (правила вывода человекочитаемых даты, времени, валюты и т. д для конкретного языка). Один и тот же `DateTime` вы можете распечатать и как `дд.мм.гггг`, и как `мм/дд/гггг`, и как-то по другому — внутренний формат самой переменной с датой от этого не изменится.

Answer (score 4):

1. Нельзя. Если только вы не используете локаль, в которой такой формат "предпочитаемый"; но поскольку это технический формат, в человеческой реальности его напрямую не используют. Так что такая локаль вряд ли существует, поскольку нет региона, где она актуальна. Но даже если бы она существовала, внутри всё равно было бы преобразование в строку. Но вы этот этап не видите. Он внутри.
2. Здесь есть некоторое непонимание.

Допустим, у вас есть строка `"FF"`, содержащая 16-ричное представление числа.

И вы пытаетесь её превратить в значение целочисленного типа. Открываете отладчик и с ужасом видите, что потерялась 16-ричность! Вместо исходного FF вы видите десятичное 255.

Паника. Недоумение.

А что если я скажу вам, что внутри там вовсе не 255? Там число в том виде, с которым **вашему** компьютеру удобнее производить вычисления, и скорее всего оно в бинарном виде: `0...0 1111 1111`.

Вот только вывести вам эти байты напрямую – плохая идея. Во-первых, это особенность того компьютера, которым вы в данный момент пользуетесь. Во-вторых, куда и как выводить? В текстовое поле? Там нужна строка, состоящая из символов. Но у вас их пока нет, только голые байты. Выводить их напрямую опасно – в используемой кодировке печатаемых символов с такими кодами может не быть вовсе.

Поэтому при выводе в любые текстовые места отладчики и многие другие средства выводят значения в тех представлениях, в которых *эти значения понятнее всего* *вам*. Для чисел это последовательности арабских десятичных цифр. Так исторически сложилось, этот формат понятен практически всему миру.

Поэтому если вам нужно вывести число в шестнадцатеричном виде, придется преобразовать его в **строку** самостоятельно *с указанием основания системы счисления*.

---

То же самое с `DateTime`. Да, он теряет формат! И внутри хранит дату в таком безумном виде, что на первый человеческий взгляд даже не будет очевидно, что это момент времени. И преобразовывать её в строку для вывода без иных явных указаний он будет в тот вид, который согласно подсказке системы (локаль) будет вам наиболее понятен.

Если же вам нужно вывести дату в ISO8601, то (как и выше) придётся явно преобразовать его в **строку** *с указанием формата*.

Такие дела.