# Как вывести случайное пятизначное число случайное трехзначное число раз?

Tags: python

Как вывести случайное пятизначное число, где сумма всех цифр четна и первая и последняя цифры равны, случайное трехзначное число раз?

Comment: Что у вас не получается?

Comment: Конкретно вывести случайное число случайное кол-во раз

Comment: Можно поконкретнее? Вы не знаете, как сгенерировать случайное число? Не понимаете как получить число, удовлетворяющее критериям? Не умеете выводить числа и пользоваться циклом? Может быть, какие-то идеи уже есть?

Comment: Знаю как сгенерировать, но как сгенерировать определенное кол-во или же рандомное не понимаю как

Comment: Используйте цикл, как было сказано выше

Comment: Перебирайте в цикле случайные числа отбирая подходящие, пока не наберется нужное кол-во. Можно и более интеллектуально подойти, например последнюю цифру устанавливать в первую, в предпоследнюю выбирать из четных или нечетных, в зависимости от четности остальных цифр.

Comment: Сумма чего должна быть чётной? // https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy цифр наверное, апичатался просто.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, можно и без цикла :) Хотя, не совсем, потому что сумму цифр всё равно циклом считать.

Comment: Да, сумма цифр)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Сгенерировать первую и последнюю цифру `digit`
2. Сгенерировать середину числа `mid`
3. Если у середины нечётная сумма цифр, уменьшить её на 1
   (первая и последняя цифры одинаковы, поэтому на чётность суммы не влияют)
4. Собрать всё в единое число

https://ideone.com/hvvZWg

```
import random

def sum_digits(x):
  res = 0

  while x:
    res += x % 10
    x //= 10

  return res

def gen_smth(N):
  digit = random.randint(1, 9)
  mid = random.randint(0, 10**N - 1)
  if sum_digits(mid) % 2: mid -= 1
  return (digit * 10**N + mid) * 10 + digit

for _ in range(100):
  print(gen_smth(3))
```

Comment: Вместо `sum_digits(mid)` подошло бы более мутное `sum(map(ord, str(mid)))` =)

Comment: @Семён, N=3 - количество цифр в центральной части (как и в [соседнем ответе](/a/762037/178988)).

Answer (score 1):

Можно сгенерировать все допустимые 5-значные числа и выбрать одно случайно:

```
import random

def valid(n):
    digits = list(map(int, str(n)))
    return digits[0] == digits[-1] and sum(digits) % 2 == 0

ndigits = 5
valid_numbers = list(filter(valid, range(10**(ndigits - 1), 10**ndigits)))
n = random.choice(valid_numbers)
```

Затем вывести его случайное трехзначное число раз:

```
for _ in range(random.randrange(100, 1000)):
    print(n)
```

Входной диапазон чисел маленький, поэтому какие-либо оптимизации здесь излишни.

Comment: Никто и не заметил, что нужно выводить одно и то же число трехзначное кол-во раз =) Плюс.

Answer (score -1):

медленный, но более понятный способ

```
import random

res = []
rnd = lambda d=5: random.randint(10**(d-1), 10**d-1)  # случайное пятизначное число
max_l = random.randint(100, 999)  # случайное трехзначное число раз

while len(res) < max_l:
    r5 = rnd(5)
    str_r = tuple(map(int, str(r5)))
    if (not sum(str_r) % 2) and (str_r[0] == str_r[-1]):  # где сумма всех чисел четна и первая и последняя цифры равны
        res.append(r5)
print(len(res), res[0])  # 859 58955
```

Answer (score -1):

Надо сгенерировать случайное число из диапазона 10000-99999. Потом сгенерировать другое число из диапазона 100-999 и задать цикл.