# Почему не работает if x % 2: --x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Если число нечётное, то уменьшить его на единицу - что неверно в следующем способе?

```
if x % 2: --x
```

Код полностью: https://ideone.com/SLZsrn

```
import random

def gen_smth():
  x = random.randint(0, 100)
  if x % 2: --x
  return x

for _ in range(100):
  print(gen_smth())
```

В выводе содержатся нечётные числа, хотя должны были получиться только чётные:

```
64
11
37
35
1
```

Comment: потому что в python нету `--x`

Comment: @diraria, тогда почему работает?

Comment: @diraria, а, понял: это два унарных минуса?

Comment: @diraria, ответ напишешь?

Comment: получается да, сейчас напишу

Comment: @diraria, зачем общим-то ответ было делать? Превратил в обычный. Через 7 минут приму.

Comment: я так и подумал что ты превратишь)

Comment: а if x % 2 это случайно не определения ченых цифр. у вас в вопросе нечетное вроде определить надо.

Comment: @BogdanKardash, нет. 0 ложный, а 1 истинная. И если бы это было определением чётных чисел, а --x работало, то все числа получились бы нечётные, а там есть и те, и другие.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В Python нету `--x`, как и `x--`, вместо них стоит использовать `x -= 1`

Ну и как Qwertiy сказал в комментариях, запись `if True: --x` работает, потому что здесь `-` используется в качестве унарного минуса

---

Может показаться странным, что `--x` является `statement` в Python, но если обратиться к [формальному определению](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html) `statement`, то получаем следующую цепочку:

[`simple_stmt`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#simple-statements) → [`expression_stmt`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-expression_stmt) → [`starred_expression`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-starred_expression)  → [`expression`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-expression) → [`conditional_expression`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-conditional_expression) → [`or_test`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-or_test) → [`and_test`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-and_test) → [`not_test`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-not_test) → [`comparison`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-comparison) → [`or_expr`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-or_expr) → [`xor_expr`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-xor_expr) → [`and_expr`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-and_expr) → [`shift_expr`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-shift_expr) → [`a_expr`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-a_expr) → [`m_expr`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-m_expr) → [`u_expr`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-u_expr), где

`u_expr` включает в себя унарные выражения.

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы увидеть как фактически код интерпретируется на выбранной версии СPython, можно [tokenize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html#tokenize), [dis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) модули использовать:

```
$ python -mtokenize <<<'--x'
1,0-1,1:            OP             '-'            
1,1-1,2:            OP             '-'            
1,2-1,3:            NAME           'x'            
1,3-1,4:            NEWLINE        '\n'           
2,0-2,0:            ENDMARKER      ''
```

то есть каждый `-` это отдельный оператор:

```
$ python -mdis <<<'--x'
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 UNARY_NEGATIVE
              4 UNARY_NEGATIVE
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

а именно `-` является унарным минусом здесь: `-(-x)`.

`x--` это SyntaxError в Питоне.

Чтобы вычесть единицу по месту в Питоне:

```
x -= 1
```

Чтобы выбрать случайное чётное число от 0 до 100 включительно:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choice(range(0, 101, 2))
42
```

Comment: Интересно. А вообще, это я вот это решал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/762063/178988, а случайное чётное там не очень в тему :)