# Как распарсить то что ввел пользователь, пример я читаю с TextBox 1-3,4,5,6 как при печати когда вводишь пользовательские страницы C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Как распарсить то что ввел пользователь, пример я читаю с TextBox 1-3,4,5,6 как при печати когда вводишь пользовательские страницы и записать их в List int и записать все диапазоны(или номера страниц) которые надо распечатать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/778367/218063

Comment: спасибо))))))))