# Как добавить незначащие нули в начало целого числа

Tags: c

Перевел число в двоичный код,но до 8 бит не хватает пару нулей в начале, есть ли возможность у целого числа в начале добавить незначащие нули ?
Перевел число в двоичный вид

```
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {

        for (z = 0; A[j] > 0; z++)
        {
            l = A[j] % 2;
            A[j] = (A[j] - l) / 2;
            l3 = l3 + l * pow(10, z);
        }


            A1[j] = l3;
            l3 = 0;
            l = 0;

    }
    putchar('\n');
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        printf("%10d", A1[j]);
    }
```

Это мне нужно, чтобы сделать код Хемминга

Comment: Понимаете, вы не о том спрашиваете. Похоже, вам нужно ВЫВЕСТИ эти нули, или добавить их к строке - но не добавить **к числу** - добавить вы моете их хоть миллион, само **число** от этого не изменится. Приведите тот фрагмент кода, где вам очень нужны эти нули...

Comment: @Harry,Лучше строкой хранить ? И в таком случае будет удобно двигать элементы строки, чтобы вставлять нули , а потом их по определенному правилу менять на единицы или оставлять нулём

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453059/10105

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то Вам нужно это:

```
printf("%010d", A1[j]);
```