# Двоичное число из строки в двоичное число типа int

Tags: c

Двоичное число хранится в символьном массиве num2and1 , хранится вот это значение:110000110001

Хочу засунуть его переменную типа int и потом перевести число в десятичное , а из него уже и в ASCII символ,а потом полученный символ записать в файл

Для этого использую код из книги K&R

```
long  n;   
        n = 0;    
        for (i = 0; num2and1[i] >= '0' && num2and1[i] <= '9'; ++i)    
            n = 10 * n + (num2and1[i] - '0');   
        printf("%d", n);
```

Но на выходе такое -1669039695.Как же всё-таки правильно перенести эти символы цифр 1 и 0 в int? И почему в Си нет двоичного представления  чисел ?

Comment: "Но на выходе такое -1669039695." - а какое должно? Видно же, что это код для десятичной записи, диапазон цифр от `'0'` до `'9'` ясно на это указывает.

Comment: @Igor, а разве не должны быть те же единички и нулики , но уже как цифры , а не символы ?(в исходном порядке)

Comment: Не понял последний комментарий.

Comment: @Igor, это не исправит положение ? num2and1[i] >= '0' && num2and1[i] <= '1'

Comment: Код, который Вы привели, преoбразует (пытается преобразовать) строку с числом "сто десять миллиардов сто десять тысяч один" в целое число. Число, конечно, в `int` не помещается, заворачивается вокруг максимального значения много раз и дает в результате мусор.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, код перевода записи числа в само число у вас приведен для перевода из *десятичной* записи. А вы, очевидно, хотите переводить из *двоичной*. Для перевода из *двоичной* записи он будет выглядеть примерно так

```
const char *num2and1 = "110000110001";

long n = 0;    
for (unsigned i = 0; num2and1[i] >= '0' && num2and1[i] <= '1'; ++i)    
  n = 2 * n + (num2and1[i] - '0');   

printf("%ld", n);
```

Во-вторых, выписывать все это руками нет никакого смысла, когда есть готовая функция перевода `strtol` в стандартной библиотеке

```
const char *num2and1 = "110000110001";

long n = strtol(num2and1, NULL, 2);

printf("%ld", n);
```

Для печати значения типа `long` нужен спецификатор формата `%ld`, а не `%d`.

В-третьих, что такое "а из него уже и в ASCII символ" - не ясно. В данном примере двоичная запись соответствует числу `3121`. Где тут "ASCII символ"?

Comment: ,а что делает NULL в strtol

Comment: @Elvin: Он говорит функции `strtol`, что вы не хотите знать, в каком месте строки остановился процесс перевода.

Comment: 3121. Где тут "ASCII символ" это же единица

Comment: "это же единица"??? Ничего не понятно.

Comment: printf("%c",3121); выводит единицу

Comment: Прекрасно. Но `printf("%c",3121);` выводит символ с кодом `(unsigned char) 3121`. К исходному `3121` это никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: ,что тогда за единицу выводит мне компилятор ?

Comment: и как записать в файл его (3121)  символьный эквивалент ?

Comment: @Elvin: одно и то же число может разным символам (и даже нескольким символам одновременно) соответствовать в зависимости от кодировки. В ascii это переводится как `FF` `1` (FORM FEED символ, за которым символ единицы идёт).

Answer (score 2):

Вы же сами говорите, что это - двоичное число. Тогда множить надо на 2:

```
n = 2 * n + (num2and1[i] - '0');
```

А так вы хотите записать 12-значное число в тип `int`, и получаете переполнение - отсюда и отрицательное значение...