# в input только цифры от 1 до 30

Tags: javascript

имеются два input'a, один из них дублирует второй, цифры переключаются при нажатии на + и - но также нужна возможность самому записать значение в поле, это значение должно быть ограничено, как раз от 1 до 30

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('keydown', '#setinputone', function(e) {
    if (e.key.length == 1 && e.key.match(/[^0-9'".]/)) {
      return false;
    };
  })

  $(document).on('click', '.plus_and_minus', function() {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    var count = parseInt($input.val());
    if ($(this).hasClass('minus')) {
      count = count <= 1 ? 30 : count - 1;
      $input.val(count);
      $('#setinputtwo').val(count);
    } else {
      count = count >= 30 ? 1 : count + 1;
      $input.val(count);
      $('#setinputtwo').val(count);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="minus plus_and_minus glyphicon glyphicon-minus coloriconmodal positionforlabel">-</a>
<input type="text" class="imputssettingmodal" id="setinputone" value="1" size="3" />
<a href="#" class="plus plus_and_minus glyphicon glyphicon-plus coloriconmodal">+</a>
<input type="text" class="imputssettingmodal positionforlabeltwo" id="setinputtwo" value="1" size="3" disabled/>
```

Comment: какие ошибки в консоли?

Comment: ошибок нет, в том то и дело, он просто позволяет мне вписать любое число, но когда я нажимаю тот же +, он возвращает к 30, но нужно чтоб не было такой возможности

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988

Comment: "цифры ... до 30" - тридцатеричная система счисления?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только цифры, сразу дублирование во второй `input`. До 30.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
var anchor = 0;
$('#setinputone').on('input', function(){
var val = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
$(this).val(val);
$('#setinputtwo').val(val);
var num = $(this).val().length;
if(val>30 || num > 2){
 val = 30;
  $(this).val(val);
  $('#setinputtwo').val(val);
}
});

  $(document).on('click', '.plus_and_minus', function() {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    var count = parseInt($input.val());
    if ($(this).hasClass('minus')) {
      count = count <= 1 ? 30 : count - 1;
      $input.val(count);
      $('#setinputtwo').val(count);
    } else {
      count = count >= 30 ? 1 : count + 1;
      $input.val(count);
      $('#setinputtwo').val(count);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="minus plus_and_minus glyphicon glyphicon-minus coloriconmodal positionforlabel">-</a>
<input type="text" class="imputssettingmodal" id="setinputone" value="1" size="3" />
<a href="#" class="plus plus_and_minus glyphicon glyphicon-plus coloriconmodal">+</a>
<input type="text" class="imputssettingmodal positionforlabeltwo" id="setinputtwo" value="1" size="3" disabled/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ввод вы фильтруете (кстати неправильно - вы зачем-то разрешаете ввод кавычек, но запрещаете клавиши перемещения курсора). А вот введенное значение не проверяете никак

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('keypress', '#setinputone', function(e) {
    if (e.key.match(/[^0-9]/)) {
      return false;
    };
    var val = this.value;
    val = val.substring(0, this.selectionStart) + e.key + val.substring(this.selectionEnd)
    var intVal = parseInt(val, 10);
    if (intVal < 0 || intVal > 30)
      return false;
    $('#setinputtwo').val(intVal);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.plus_and_minus', function() {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    var count = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
    if ($(this).hasClass('minus')) {
      count = count <= 1 ? 30 : count - 1;
      $input.val(count);
      $('#setinputtwo').val(count);
    } else {
      count = count >= 30 ? 1 : count + 1;
      $input.val(count);
      $('#setinputtwo').val(count);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="minus plus_and_minus glyphicon glyphicon-minus coloriconmodal positionforlabel">-</a>
<input type="text" class="imputssettingmodal" id="setinputone" value="1" size="3" />
<a href="#" class="plus plus_and_minus glyphicon glyphicon-plus coloriconmodal">+</a>
<input type="text" class="imputssettingmodal positionforlabeltwo" id="setinputtwo" value="1" size="3" disabled/>
```

Comment: При вводе я могу пойти дальше по странице, а значение в input disabled, будет разниться с введенным.

Comment: Блин, ну добавьте одну строчку кода. Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

А вот еще один вариант. Он защищает еще и от вставки из буфера обмена

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('keypress', '#setinputone', function(e) {
    if (e.key.match(/[^0-9]/)) {
      return false;
    };
    var val = this.value;
    val = val.substring(0, this.selectionStart) + e.key + val.substring(this.selectionEnd)
    var intVal = parseInt(val, 10);
    if (intVal < 0 || intVal > 30)
      return false;
    $('#setinputtwo').val(intVal);
  });

  $(document).on('input', '#setinputone', function(e) {
    var val = (!this.value.match(/^\d+$/)) ? -1 : parseInt(this.value, 10);
    if (val < 1) {
      val = 1;
      this.value = val;
    } else if (val > 30) {
      val = 30;
      this.value = val;
    }
    $('#setinputtwo').val(val);
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.plus_and_minus', function() {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    var count = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
    var delta = ($(this).hasClass('minus')) ? -1: 1;
    count = ((count - 1 + delta) % 30) + 1;
    if (count <= 0)
      count += 30;
    $input.val(count);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="minus plus_and_minus glyphicon glyphicon-minus coloriconmodal positionforlabel">-</a>
<input type="text" class="imputssettingmodal" id="setinputone" value="1" size="3" />
<a href="#" class="plus plus_and_minus glyphicon glyphicon-plus coloriconmodal">+</a>
<input type="text" class="imputssettingmodal positionforlabeltwo" id="setinputtwo" value="1" size="3" disabled/>
```

Answer (score 0):

А вот ещё один вариант

```html
<form>
  <input type=number min=1 max=30 value=1 step=1 required=true/>
  <input type=submit>
</form>
```