# Конвертация бинарного int в hex int

Tags: c#

К примеру, у меня есть число:

```
Int binare = 461;
```

Как можно его перевести в hex, чтобы в конце переменная была тоже int, а не string?

Что-то типа такого:

```
int binare = 461;

int output_hex = 0x1CD;
```

Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. Десятичное и шестнадцатеричное представления чисел — это исключительно для удобства программиста. Всё равно при компиляции всё переводится в двоичную систему счисления, то есть последовательность бит, понятную процессору.

Answer (score 3):

Не нужно ничего переводить. Hex, deс и т.д. - это только строковое представление чисел для людей

И `461` и `0x1CD` в памяти компьютера одинаковы

Answer (score 1):

В памяти компьютера все числа представлены в 2-ичной системе и нет разницы какой системой ты его задашь, она всё равно будет храниться в 2. Скорее всего ты хочешь его отображать в `hex` формате, то воспользуйся `Convert.ToString (Int32, Int32)` методом для вывода числа в `hex` формате.

---

А для чего это вообще вам нужно?

Comment: Скорее всего это нужно, для формирования пакета из массива байт, для передачи через COM Port на микроконтроллер -
потому, что я здесь из за этого.)))