# Как узнать, делится ли число нацело в двоичной системе счисления

Tags: python

```
a = int(input())

b = ` `

while a > 0:
    b = str(a % 2) + b
    a = a // 2

print(b)

k = int(input())

c = ''

while k > 0:
    c = str(k % 2) + c
    k = k // 2

print(c)

if b % c == 0:
    print("%d делится на %d" % (b, c))
else:
    print("%d не делится на %d" % (b, c))
    print("Остаток: %d" % (b % c))
print("Частное: %d" % (b // c))
```

Comment: Это русскоязычный ресурс, пожалуйста, пишите здесь на русском языке.

Comment: @MaxU, вроде очевидно, что a на k.

Comment: @Qwertiy Это очевидно из чего?

Comment: @Эникейщик, из кода... Я бы тоже предпочел явный вопрос в виде текста...

Comment: @Эникейщик, из кода и заголовка.

Comment: @Qwertiy, мне кажется в заголовке стоит поменять `число` --> `числа`? Сам менять не буду, т.к. уже дан ответ на вопрос в его текущем виде...

Comment: @MaxU, вроде тоже как-то странно звучит. Числа не клетки, чтобы делением размножаться))) По идее должно быть "делится ли одно число на другое", но как-то для заголовка длинновато. А почему ты считаешь, что от этого изменится смысл вопроса, я вообще не понял. Кстати, в оригинале было в единственном числе.

Answer (score 1):

[Число либо делится, либо не делится - от системы счисления это не зависит.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988)

Насколько я вижу, код в вопросе почти верный, но

> ```
> if b % c == 0:
>     print("%d делится на %d" % (b, c))
> else:
>     print("%d не делится на %d" % (b, c))
>     print("Остаток: %d" % (b % c))
> print("Частное: %d" % (b // c))
> ```

здесь для арифметических операций надо использовать a и k вместо b и c.

И ещё несколькими оговорок:

- число вводится в десятичной системе счисления, а выводится в двоичной - не уверен, что надо именно так, возможно надо наоборот при вводе из двоичной переводить в число.
- перевод стоило бы вынести в отдельную функцию, чтобы не копипастить. К тому же, есть вероятность, что он сделан неэффективно из-за добавления в начало строки.