# Visual Basic - Перевод из процентов в дроби (Выражение)

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic

Мне нужно написать код (выражение, например A / B * 100 & "%" - но только наоборот) для перевода из процентов в дроби, например, чтобы из 40% процентов переводил на 2/5 (т.е. дробь).
Я попробовал сделать это, но ответ не тот, в итоге - 250.
Вот мой код:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
Dim X = Val(TextBox1.Text) 
Dim prosto 
prosto = 100 / ((X) / (10)) 
TextBox2.Text = prosto 
End Sub
```

Можете объяснить, в чем проблема?

Comment: В том, что дробь - это два числа, а не одно. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988, правда про дроби там нет, но смысл тот же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Dim Parts = (TextBox1.Text.TrimEnd("%"c) & ".").Split(".")
TextBox2.Text = Parts(0) & Parts(1) & " / 100" & New String("0"c, Parts(1).Length)
```