# Разбить строку на равные части определенной длины с известным количеством чисел в ней?

Tags: c#

Пользователь вводит через пробел строку чисел в консоль. Мне нужно разбить её на группы по 4 числа. Заранее мне не известно сколько таких будет групп. Помогите разобраться как это реализовать? 
Пример: 
мы вводим "1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2", и мне нужно разбить эту строку на "1 1 1 1", "0 0 0 0" и "2 2 2 2". Заранее мне не известно, что нужно разбить на 3 подстроки, но известно что в подстроке будут находиться по 4 числа

Comment: 4 числа или 4 цифры?

Comment: нужно 4 числа .

Comment: @Kerrrill, а чем число отличается от цифры? :)

Comment: @LLENN, цифры это от 1 до 9 и 0, а числа это 26, 55 и т.д.)))))

Comment: @LLENN, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988

Answer (score 0):

Подключаем библиотеку [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ).

Пишем элементарный код:

```
string s = "1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2";
var batches = s.Split().Batch(4);
```

В `batches` 3 группы по 4 числа.

Если необходимы именно строки, дописываем в конец:

```
.Select(b => string.Join(" ", b))
```

Или ещё проще:

```
.Batch(4, b => string.Join(" ", b))
```

Не забываем открыть пространства имён:

```
using System.Linq;
using MoreLinq;
```

Если не хочется тянуть в проект лишнюю библиотеку, то разбиение на группы делается элементарно без неё.

Comment: Может быть утеряна информация о количестве пробелов между числами (если она важна, конечно)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать регулярное выражение `(\d+\W+){3}\d+`:

```
var input = "1 2  3  4 12  23 34 45 123 234  345 456";
var pattern = @"(\d+\W+){3}\d+";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
foreach (Match match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Если в последней части может быть меньше четырех чисел, регулярку можно подправить до такой: `(\d+\W+){0,3}\d+`