# Калькулятор двоичных чисел

Tags: c

В общем, нужно сделать калькулятор двоичных вещественных чисел на си, пробовал через костыль: переводил в десятичную СС, выполнял арифметические операции и потом переводил обратно в двоичную, но такой способ не особо подходит, потому что во первых это костыль,  а во вторых  считать вещественные числа таким способом либо невозможно, либо это еще больший костыль. Я полагаю что можно реализовать все с помощью побитовых операций, поэтому нужна подсказка. Как и какие побитовые операции следует использовать для сложения, вычитания и умножения двоичных вещественный чисел?

Comment: Открыть любой онлайн калькулятор с описанием и реализовать? не?

Comment: @Andrey не находил ни одного калькулятора с описанием, который работал бы не через тот же костыль, что и у меня

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988

Comment: Я думаю на github все есть, надо только поискать

Comment: @Andrey там все какое-то супер сложное, а я как бы новичок и если преподу принесу что-то подобное тому, что есть на github, то он мне скажет "сынок, это даже я не знаю, куда ты лезешь"

Comment: @seregaparich так не копируйте под чистую, соберите, отладчиком побегайте, посмотрите как работает. Дальше перепишите под себя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы дали **абсолютно**  неконкретное описание задачи...

1. Допускается ли сложное выражение (типа: 2.3 / 4.7 * 101.9) ?
2. Допускаются ли скобки в выражении (типа (2.0 + 3.0) / 7.6)  ?
3. Допускается ли смесь целых и вещественных констант?
4. Нужен ли графический интерфейс?

Ну и много ещё чего. Если ответ на все эти вопросы "Да", то программа становится достаточно сложной и вряд-ли может являться темой лабораторной работы. Поэтому, предполагаю, что на самом деле, задание было сформулировано как-то так:

1. Ввести первый операнд
2. Ввести второй операнд
3. Ввести знак операции
4. Выполнить вычисление
5. Напечатать результат.

Для такой простой задачи код может выглядеть как-то так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <math.h>

// Функция преобразования чтроки вида 10101011.011100 в число float
// cp - входная строка из символов нулей, единиц и точки
// Возвращает занчение типа float, полученное из этой строки 
float char2float(char *in_string) {

// Разбиваем строку на целую и дробную часть
char *cp_dot, *cp_fract;
int len_int, len_fract;
int val_int, val_fract;
int j;

    cp_dot = index(in_string, '.'); // Положение точки в строке
    *cp_dot = '\0'; // Разрезали строку на целую и дробную часть
    cp_fract = cp_dot + 1; // Начало дробной части
    len_int = strlen(in_string);
    len_fract = strlen(cp_fract);
    if (cp_fract[len_fract-1] == 0x0A) {
        cp_fract[len_fract-1] = '\0';
        len_fract = strlen(cp_fract);
    } 

    // Значение целой части
    val_int = 0;
    for(j=0; j< len_int; j++) {
        val_int = val_int << 1;
        if (in_string[j] == '1') val_int += 1;
    }

    // Значение дробной части
    val_fract = 0;
    for(j=0; j< len_fract; j++) {
        val_fract = val_fract << 1;
        if (cp_fract[j] == '1') val_fract += 1;
    }

    // Обединяем целую и дробную части в одно число
    float a = val_int;
    float b = val_fract;
    b = b / powf(2.0, (float)len_fract);

    return a + b;

}


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

float a, b, c;
char op;
char buf[32];

    printf("Введите первый операнд: ");
    fgets(buf, 32, stdin);
    a = char2float(buf);
    printf("Введите второй операнд: ");
    fgets(buf, 32, stdin);
    b = char2float(buf);
    printf("Введите знак операции: ");
    while( (op = getchar()) == 0x0A);

    //Выполнить вычисление
    switch(op) {
        case '+':
            c = a+b;
            break;
        case '-':
            c = a-b;
            break;
        case '*':
            c = a*b;
            break;
        case '/':
            c = a/b;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Неизвестная операция: %x\n", op);
    }

    // Напечатать результат.
    printf("Результат вычислений: %6.3f\n", c);
}
```

При запуске получаем:

```
$ ./a.out 
Введите первый операнд: 110.110
Введите второй операнд: 1.0
Введите знак операции: *
Результат вычислений:  6.750
```

Comment: Задание было сформировано именно так, как вы подумали, только ввод и вывод данных должен быть в двоичной системе счисления, в трёх словах, это должен быть калькулятор двоичных чисел

Comment: @seregaparich * калькулятор двоичных чисел* - двоичных - в смысле **записанных** нулями и единичками? Тогда уточнение: целых или вещественных?

Comment: да, нулями и единичками, вещественных

Comment: Тогда это достаточно непростая задача. 1) Вещественные числа имеют не очень простое представление в памяти, к тому же - **разное** на разных архитектурах. Почитайте вот эту статью: https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB

Comment: на самом деле, я думаю что преподаватель хочет чтобы я сделал в достаточно неправильном представлении, когда целая и вещественная часть переводятся в двоичную СС отдельно, а между ними просто ставится точка

Comment: @seregaparich Сразу вопрос - так в какую сторону Вы собрались переводить ?! Переменную типа *float* в строку из нулей и единичек, в которой где-то стоит точка, или наоборот: строку - в число ? Перевод строки в число обсуждался очень много где.

Comment: выходит что  строки в число

Comment: Добавил текст функции...