# Не могу понять упражнение и как перевести число в другую систему счисления

Tags: javascript

Дали вот такое упражнение:
Объяви переменные и присвой им цифровые значения в различных системах счисления: 
* переменную myHex с шестнадцатеричным значением, эквивалентным 400 в десятичной системе

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявить переменную в 16 системе счисления возможно вот так:

```js
let myHex = 0x190 // 400 в A-тичной

console.log(myHex)
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть способ напрямую представить число в JS для 16-ной, 8-ной и 2-ной (соответственно `0x...`, `0o...`, `0b...`) системы счислений. Для получения строкового представления числа в других системах счислений можно использовать функцию `Number.toString(2-36)`. Для обратного преобразования строк в число `parseInt(строка, основание)`:

```js
let int = 400;

console.log('0b110010000 : ' + 0b110010000); // 400 в 2-ой, то есть 0b...
console.log('0o620 : ' + 0o620); // 400 в 8-ой, 0o...
console.log('0x190 : ' + 0x190); // 400 в 16-ой, 0x...


let fromInt = {
  2 : int.toString(2), 
  4 : int.toString(4),
  8 : int.toString(8),
  16 : int.toString(16),
  32 : int.toString(32)
}

for(let key in fromInt){
   console.log(`400 в ${key}-ой системе счислений: ${fromInt[key]}`);
   fromInt[key] = parseInt(fromInt[key], key); // Преобразовываем строки в число
}

console.log('Объект после преобразований:', fromInt); // Получаем везде 400
```

То есть для получения значения числа `Num` в `n`-ой системе счислений: `Num.toString(n)`, дальше подставлять это значение после `0b для двоичных`, `0o для восьмеричных` и `0x для шестнадцатеричных`. Ведь надо же как то сначала вычислить значение нужного числа в этих форматах))