# Вывести числа строки, которые отсутствуют в проверочном списке

Tags: python

```
def func(s):
    li = []
    s = list(s)
    check = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    for i in check:
        if i not in s:
            li.append(i)
    return li

s = '9832209763'
func(s) >> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Функция вроде бы должна вывести [1,4,5]

Comment: `if not str(i) in s:`

Comment: `list(set(check)-set(map(int, list(s))))`

Comment: @splash58 Только сейчас увидел, что уже в комментариях ответы есть, после того как свой ответ написал. Могу только заметить, что `list(s)` - избыточно, `map` и без него строку спокойно проитерирует.

Comment: 1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988 2. Ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 3):

Твоя ошибка во время проверки:"if i not in s".
Все числа из проверочного списка, имею тип int, а строка str, соответсвенно число не может быть в строке. Поэтомy надо написать: "if str(i) not in s".

Comment: думал, что если переделываю стринг в список тогда и преобразование происходит ) ok спасибо

Comment: @nich123 , будьте добры, если ответ Вам помог, пожалуйста, отметьте его на правильный. Это стимулирует пользователей на дальнейшую помощь.

Comment: стрелочку нажал, а что еще?

Answer (score 1):

Но вообще можно тоже самое сделать гораздо короче - через разность множеств. Преобразование символов строки в числа у меня сделано через `map(int, s)`:

```
s = '9832209763'
check = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
print(check.difference(map(int, s)))
```

На выходе:

```
{1, 4, 5}
```

Если на выходе надо получить именно список, то надо взять `list()` от результата. Сейчас у меня на выходе множество.

P.S. Вообще-то код у вас решает задачу, обратную той, что заявлена в вопросе - выводит те цифры из проверочного списка, которых не найдено в строке.