# Есть ли какая-нибудь операция для склеивания чисел. Не сложение двух чисел, а склеивание их

Tags: c#

Например просто + складывает два числа и получается 1+2=3, но мне надо склеить, чтобы 1+2=12. Конвертировать в строку, а потом обратно в int не хочется. Я слышал в математике есть такая операция, не помню как называется, но работает также, так что наверняка это есть и в программировании.

Comment: нет такой операции. Ты можешь умножить одно число на 10^(количество цифр) другого числа и сложить

Comment: а известно заранее кол-во цифр?

Comment: @axmed2004, числа ж передаются

Comment: Такая операция называется конкатенация, и это строковая операция. Математические операции не могут давать различный результат при изменении системы счисления.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988. Чисел или цифр?

Comment: Ответ исправлен - вспомнил про 1.

Comment: Есть такая операция. Называется "JavaScript" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если речь идёт о цифрах (или хотя бы второй элемент - цифра), то

```
var res = x * 10 + y;
```

Если это два числа и разрядность второго `n`, то

```
var res = x * Math.Pow(10, n) + y;
```

Если лидирующие нули не нужны у второго числа, то примерно (могут быть ошибки из-за погрешности вычислений и округления):

```
var res = x * Math.Pow(10, Math.Ceil(Math.Log10(y + 1))) + y;
```

или (не уверен в осмысленности):

```
var p = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(y));
while (p <= y) p *= 10;
var res = x * p + y;
```

или

```
var p = 10;
while (p <= y) p *= 10;
var res = x * p + y;
```

PS: Формулы не проверял, но вроде должны быть такие.