# перевод чисел в байты вида 0x00

Tags: c++, arduino

На вход будут поступать числа, значение датчика расстояния, мне нужно перевести их к виду
0x01, 0x20, 0xA0, 0x00 первые биты младшие

например число 400 должно быть в виде 0x90, 0x01

Что бы подставить в выражение:
unsigned char stmp[8] = {0x90, 0x01};

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "mcp_can.h"

const int SPI_CS_PIN = 10;


MCP_CAN CAN(SPI_CS_PIN);

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
while (CAN_OK != CAN.begin(CAN_250KBPS, MCP_8MHz))
    {
      Serial.println("CAN BUS Shield init fail");
      Serial.println(" INit CAN BUS Shield again");
      delay(100); 
      }

    Serial.println("CAN BUS Shield Init OK!");
}
// Пробег
unsigned char stmp[8] = {0x90, 0x01};

    
void loop()
{   
  Serial.println("In loop");
  CAN.sendMsgBuf(0x18FEC1EE, 1, 8, stmp);
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: Вопрос - что вы собираетесь дальше с этим набором байт делать?

Comment: Кстати, байты 0x90, 0x01 - это 400, а не 200

Comment: Да я забыл исправить) 200 занимает 1 байт, после 
unsigned char stmp[8] = {0x90, 0x01};
    
void loop()
{   
  Serial.println("In loop");
  CAN.sendMsgBuf(0x18FEC1EE, 1, 8, stmp);
  delay(100);
}

Comment: Добавил  код, программа для передачи данных для GPS модуля

Comment: Чисто в качестве идеи, попробуйте сделать массив `unsigned int stmp[2] = {400, 0};` и отправку как `CAN.sendMsgBuf(0x18FEC1EE, 1, 8, (unsigned char *)stmp);`

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вам например из `unsigned int number = 400` надо получить `unsigned char stmp[8] = {0x90, 0x01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};`?

Comment: Стандартный алгоритм: бьёте чило на две части по 4 бита. Верхняя часть `у = у / 16;` или сдвиг на 4, нижняя часть `y = x & 15;` Далее 0-15 преобразуем в ASCII: `y = ((x > 9) ?(65 - 10) : 48) + x;` усё.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988

Comment: В каком диапазоне значения поступающих чисел, могут ли они быть отрицательными?

Comment: 0 до 200 значения с датчика расстояния

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unsigned char stmp[8] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int number = 400;
*((int*)stmp) = number;
```

Чтобы избежать приведения типа (вдруг компилятор так строго настроен), можно использовать более хитрый код:

```
typedef union {
    unsigned char uc_array[8];
    unsigned int ui_number;
} stmp_t;
stmp_t stmp;

number = 400;

stmp.ui_number = number;

CAN.sendMsgBuf(0x18FEC1EE, 1, 8, stmp.uc_array);
```

Comment: Нарушение strict aliasing → UB.

Comment: Запись одного поля `union`, а чтение из другого — тоже UB.

Comment: @Vanyamba Electronics
~~~
void loop()
{   
  Serial.println("In loop");
  typedef union 
  {
  unsigned char uc_array[8];
  unsigned int ui_number;
  } stmp_t;
  stmp_t stmp;
  int number = 400;
  stmp.ui_number = number;
  CAN.sendMsgBuf(0x18FEC1EE, 1, 8, stmp.uc_array); 
  CAN.sendMsgBuf(0x18FEC1EE, 1, 8, stmp);
  delay(100);
}
~~~
Пишет ошибку 

can:28:40: error: no matching function for call to 'MCP_CAN::sendMsgBuf(long int, int, int, loop()::stmp_t&)'
   CAN.sendMsgBuf(0x18FEC1EE, 1, 8, stmp);