# Написать функцию, которая принимает любое число и возвращает сумму первого и последнего числа

Tags: c++, функции, математика

Всех приветствую.

Есть такая задача: надо написать функцию, которая принимает на вход любое целочисленное число, а на выходе возвращает сумму первого и последнего числа. Иными словами, если на входе 1234, необходимо, чтобы программа нашла первое число (в нашем случае это 1) и последнее (4) и в итоге сложила эти два числа. Вот что я написал, но как я уже понял ошибка в оформлении int First и int Last. Не могу найти ответ и понять как правильно описать условия, чтобы выдавало что нужно. Заранее спасибо всем за подсказки и ответы.

```
    int SumOfFirstAndLast(int Number) {
        while (Number >= 10) {
            Number /= 10;
        }
        int First = Number % 10;
        int Last = Number % 10 + Number;
        return First + Last;
    }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988

Comment: 1 и 4 в данном случае цифры, а не числа.

Comment: Первое число - 12, последнее 34 :) Докажите, что это не так! Вы бы хотя бы упомянули "однозначное"...

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим на входном примере: `1234`

Нам нужно, чтобы функция вернула `1 + 4 = 5`

Не торопимся сразу портить входное значения, а получим сначала последнюю цифру при помощи деления с остатком на 10.

`int Last = Number % 10 <-> int Last = 1234 % 10 = 4`

Теперь нам надо получить первую цифру, для этого нужно избавится от трех последних цифр при помощи деления на 10.

С циклом вы сделали все правильно, он должен делить число на 10, пока >= 10.

`Number = 1234 / 10 = 123 -> 123 / 10 = 12 -> 12 / 10 = 1`

Получаем `int First = Number <-> int First = 1`

Возвращаем результат: `return First + Last <-> return 1 + 4 <-> return 5`

Answer (score 0):

1. Поздно считать последнюю цифру когда ты уже испортил число.
2. Сложение есть в `return`, а другое - лишнее.
3. Ну отладчик же существует.
4. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988