# Как перевести число с десятичной системой счисления в число с основание "3" ? Python

Tags: python

Значение арифметического выражения: 9^18 + 3^54 – 9 — записали в системе счисления с основанием 3. Сколько цифр «2» содержится в этой записи?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988

Answer (score 2):

можно записать в виде

```
9^18 + 3^54 – 9 = 3^27 + 3^54 - 3^2 = 3^2 * (3^52 + 3^25 - 1)
```

т.е. это число

```
3^2  * (0t100000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000 - 1)
```

умножение на `3^2` даст сдвиг влево на 2 разряда, которые будут нулевыми

а вычитание 1 из 0 даст2

автор может сам вычесть эту единичку и подсчитать сколько получится двоек

**P.S.**

а если надо сделать на питоне, то вычисление соответствующего разряда - это итерационное выполнение следующей команды

```
digit = value % 3
value //= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

> Сколько цифр «2» содержится

Для этого вообще не надо переводить никуда.

```
res = 0

while x:
  res += x % 3 == 2
  x //= 3
```

А переводится аналогично, только цифры сохраняем в массив, а потом его переворачиваем.

А если число уже разложено на нужные слагаемые, то надо просто их сгруппировать и пересчитать.