# Новогодний арифметический конкурс 2022

Tags: математика, олимпиада, арифметика, соревнование

Это конкурс должен был объявлять придумавший его Harry, но он почему-то передумал. Поэтому я за него ))

Вот условия конкурса:

---

Пока некоторые рисуют елочки, предлагаю заняться более умственной работой :)

Новогодний коннкурс на 2022 год (который, кстати, находится как раз посредине между двумя простыми годами — 2017 и 2027).

Задача — представить число 2022 с помощью как можно меньшего количества одинаковых цифр.

Можно использовать скобки, арифметические операции, возведение в степень, квадратный корень, факториал или двойной факториал (напомню, что двойной факториал для нечетного — произведение всех нечетных, не превышающих данное число, для четного — соответственно четных). Две номинации - только для "скобки, арифметические операции, возведение в степень", и вторая — разрешено всё выше перечисленное.

И еще — то же самое для ряда цифр 1234567890 и 9876543210 - постараться по возможности получить 2022 для всех подпоследовательностей — ну, там, для 1234567, 12345678 и так далее. Ноль не должен быть тривиальным (например, в конце +0)!

Поскольку конкурс чисто развлекательный, пусть победителя определит голосование за ответы. Понятно, что чем меньше цифр использовано — тем круче решение. Не менее важна и эстетика решения.

Чтобы было понятнее, что требуется — вот несколько решений для 2021 года:

```
1-(1+1)*(1-11111)/11
((999+99/9)*(9+9)+9)/9
((9+9)/9)^(99/9)-9-9-9 
((9+9)/9)^(99/9)-sqrt(9)*9
((9-8)*7*6+5)*43
1*2+3+4*(56+7)*8
```

---

Срок конкурса ограничим 5 днями, чтобы не затягивать. По договоренности, Harry участвует вне конкурса, чтобы не могло быть никаких претензий, что он заранее долго думал. Т.е. он может участвовать, но не может быть объявлен победителем.

От себя объявляю приз победителю в 400 баллов, но приглашаю спонсоров поучаствовать и наградить понравившихся участников и решения.

Comment: Я готов 200 репы победителю отдать

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал в ответах — чтоб сразу было видно — указывать количество использованных цифр.

Comment: Не могу найти информацию: я могу поделиться своей репутацией с победителем?

Comment: @Dmitry Вы знаете, я сам это первый раз делаю. Видел в других конкурсах присвоение нескольких наград, думал, что это просто. Надо у специалистов спрашивать.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вы тут и участник, и модератор - не можете как специалист подсказать что и как (комментарии выше)?

Comment: `1-(1+1)*(1-11111)/11` а это к какому заданию относится?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru это же пример того, что надо, для 2021 года

Comment: При всем уважении к avp, по истечении 5 дней победителем объявляется @Qwertiy — у него при равных баллах решений больше, и они в рамках условий. Спасибо всем участникам!

Comment: @Mikhailo, я понимаю что для 2021, но как-то это решение не подходит для `как можно меньшего количества одинаковых цифр.`

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Хорошо, мы посмеялись вашей шутке. Если вы будете и дальше делать вид, что не понимаете условие - от меня ответа не ждите, тем более что конкурс закончен.

Answer (score 17):

###### pwsh

```
# единственный ноль
[int]"$($$=0)$(++$$)$$$(--$$)$$$(++$$)$$$$"*(++$$)
# единственная единица
[int]"$($$=1)$$$(--$$)$$$(++$$)$$$$"*(++$$)
# ещё вариант с единицей (трюк с бинарной системой счисления)
[int][Convert]::ToString("$($$=1)$$$$", ($$=$$+$$))*$$
# совсем без цифр
[int]"$($$=!!{}+!!{})$$$([int]!{})$$$$"
```

###### js

```js
// шесть единиц (всё тот же трюк с бинарной системной счисления)
console.log(Number(11).toString(1+1)*(1+1));
// пять четвёрок (трюк с троичной системой счисления)
console.log(Number((4<<4)-Math.sqrt(4)).toString(4-(Math.log(4)^{})));
// семь шестёрок
console.log(((6<<6)+~6*6-6+(Math.log(6)^{}))*6);
// шесть семёрок
console.log(Math.abs((~7<<7)*Math.log(7)+(~7<<Math.log2(7))+Math.log(7))^{});
// пять восьмёрок
console.log(((8<<8)-8*Math.sqrt(8)-Math.sqrt(8))^{});
// семь девяток
console.log((Math.sqrt(9e9|9)/(9+9/9)-Math.sqrt(9))^{});
// "горбатая" последовательность (все цифры)
console.log(1e3*2+5*4+7-6+9-8);
// число Непера и π (до кучи)
console.log((Math.E^{})**((Math.E*Math.PI+Math.E)^{})-((Math.PI<<Math.E)*(Math.E^{})+Math.E^{}));
```

###### Математика

Небольшое отступление по теме математических констант. Теоретически в каждой из них можно отыскать число, равное текущему году. И вот здесь-то на память приходит **ζ(3)** (постоянная Апери), первые три цифры которой после запятой очень близки к текущему году:

```js
var Ap = 1.2020569031595942; // значение постоянной Апери
console.log(parseInt((-~!{}+Ap).toFixed(3).replace(/\./, '').split('').reverse().join('')));
```

Также кое-что можно экстрагировать из области тригонометрии:

```js
// функция перевода радианов в градусы
const r2d = radians => (radians * 180) / Math.PI;
// семь троек
console.log(parseInt(r2d(33+3)-((3<<-(~3))+~3+~3)));
```

Среди прочего можно обратиться к так называемым *совершенным числам*, четвёртое число последовательности которых равно `8128`, а значит получить желаемое `2022` можно посредством *четырёх четверок* (псевдокод):

```
PerfectNum(4)/4+~4*Math.sqrt(4)
```

Вообще, числовые последовательности довольно занимательная вещь. Если использовать *числа Леонардо*, `2022` можно выразить посредством четырёх семёрок:

```js
const leo = n => [...Array(n)].fill(1).reduce(
  (arr, pre, cur) => cur > 1 ? (
    arr.push(arr[cur - 1] + arr[cur - 2] + pre) && arr
  ) : arr, [1, 1]
).slice(-1)[0];
// итого - четыре семёрки
console.log(leo(Math.abs(~7+~7))+7*7);
```

###### UPD

Некоторое дополнение (к решению @avp) по поводу систем счисления. В принципе, можно использовать любую из них, чтобы получить заветное `2022`, совершая различные операции исключительно над каким-то одним числом (пусть той же двойкой). В троичной системе `2022` "соответствует" десятичное `62`, получить которое можно, скажем, так `(~2-2)*~2*2*2+2`; в системе счисления по основанию четыре - 138, т.е. `(~2<<2)**2+(~2+~2)` и т.д.

Comment: чтобы вызвать метод числа, не обязательно его в Number оборачивать, достаточно две точки поставить: `11..toString()`

Comment: @Grundy, или пробел с точкой: `11 .toString()` или в скобки его: `(11).toString()`.

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо! Только вот набив не одну оскомину с двумя точками, взял за правило писать через `Number`, в конечном коде обычно оставляю только скобки, как указал @Qwertiy

Answer (score 17):

От 0 до 9:

```js
f=n=>n<2?1:n*f(n-1)
F=n=>n<2?1:n*F(n-2)
v=Math.sqrt

console.log(((f(0)<<F(f(0)<<f(0)<<f(0)))-f(0)-f(0)-f(0)<<f(0)<<f(0)<<f(0))-f(0)^f(0))
console.log((1+1)**11-(11+1+1)*(1+1))
console.log(2222-222+22)
console.log((333*3+3*3+3)*f(3)/3)
console.log((4444-444+44)/F(4)*4)
console.log(F(55/5)/5-55-5^5)
console.log(6**6/F(6)*(66&6)+66+6+6)
console.log(F(7)*F(7)/7+77*7-77-7-7-7/7)
console.log(8888-888+88>>(8/8+8/8))
console.log(f(9)/F(9)*9/v(9)|999&~9)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Неожиданная идея: поскольку `~x` = `-x-1`, можно использовать комбинацию `-~x` как `x+1`, а в таком случае из любой цифры можно сделать 2022 используя только их. Вот, например, вариант из одного 0:

```js
console.log(-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~0)
```

И небольшой финт на js, на который меня натолкнул [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1367750/178988) и комментарии к нему:

```js
console.log(2+[2-2]+2+2)
```

Answer (score 16):

Только из одиночных цифр 2

В шестнадцатиричной системе счисления:

```
((2 << 2 << 2) << (2 << 2)) + (2 << 2 << 2) + 2 == 0x2022
```

В десятичной:

```
(2 << ((2 << 2) + 2)) - (2 << 2 << 2) + (2 << 2) - 2 == 2022
```

В десятичной, используя только разрешенные операции `+`, `-` и `*` (на Lisp)

```
(+ (- (* 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2) (* 2 2 2 2 2)) 2 2 2)
```

*(19 двоек (но только 4 знака операций (не считая 4-х пар скобок)))*

Comment: Не хватает восьмеричного варианта. Например, так `(((2<<(2<<2))+(2<<2))*2)+2`, или так `(2<<(2<<2)|2<<2)*2|2`. [Тест](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50c0c5775d26ca15).

Comment: @wololo, спасибо,  но лучше добавьте своим ответом

Comment: Мне нравится ваш ответ, но сразу должен предупредить, что он использует не перечисленные операции, а потому при всей красоте победителем стать не может... Но у вас еще есть время на другие варианты! :)

Comment: @Mikhailo, ну, на нет и суда нет (а вы можете расширть набор операций, добавив те, что существуют в реальном железе)

Answer (score 16):

Раз все равно вне конкурса, то формальности соблюдать не буду :)

Внизу табличка. Слева — то, чего удалось достичь с использованием факториалов, степеней и так далее, справа — только арифметика.

Что касается последовательностей 123... и 987... — то лучшее, что смог, это начать с 123456, и то с использованием степени и факториала; 1234567 и далее — чистая арифметика.

В обратном направлении — 98765 и 987654 — с факториалами, бифакториалами и радикалами; чистой арифметикой удалось только с 9876543.

Понравилась идея avp, сам у себя попросил разрешения использовать битовые операции, сдвиги и остаток от деления, и сам себе разрешил.

Удалось улучшить результат для всех цифр, кроме 2 и 6. Для последовательностей удалось получить 9876. Лучше ничего не получается.

Еще мне понравилась идея Qwertiy c нулями. Объединив ее со сдвигами avp, удалось обойтись десятью нулями (без битовых операций — двенадцатью, но я уже не стал включать этот результат).

Потом я разрешил себе побитовое отрицание, улучшил результат для 2 и добился последовательности 12345... но... Мне эти результаты представляются сомнительными — в том плане, что их смешение с арифметикой, вообще говоря, зависит от используемой при расчетах архитектуры. Поэтому, если бы я участвовал на общих основаниях, я бы не стал публиковать результаты с битовыми операциями. Математика есть математика :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Возможно, где-то налепил лишних скобок. Ну плохо я помню все эти приоритеты... Да и не привязано задание к языку программирования.

Comment: После вашей "ковровой бомбардировки" конкурс почти теряет смысл :( Кстати, я согласен, что надо убрать ваши варианты с `~` совсем - на компьютере оно посчитает, но математически (с числами бесконечного размера) это будет совсем неверный результат.

Comment: @Mikhailo, по идее, `~x` = `-x-1` и от битности не зависит.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну, может... надо хорошо думать, насколько это так... Что-то сразу не могу сообразить.

Answer (score 12):

```js
// Да кому в 2022 нужны эти цифры?!
console.log( +(!+[]+!![]+[])+(+[]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+[]) );

// Использованы все цифры 

console.log( 0.123e4+(5^6)+789 );
console.log( +([]+(0*1+2+3+4+5+6)+(7^(8+9))) );
console.log( 2*(10+(9-8+3*4)*(5+6)*7) );//чуть не по порядку

// Шесть двоек

console.log( 2222-2e2 );

// Просто баловство 
// (может, кого натолкнет на новые мысли)
   
console.log( 123456 ^ 124326 );
console.log( 123456789 ^ 123456243 );
console.log( 012345 ^ ([]+(6*8)+67) );
```

Answer (score 11):

### Кратчайшее решение: 9 двоек

Единицы:

```
(11111-1)/11*(1+1)+1+1
(1+1)^11-(1+1)*11-(1+1)*(1+1)
```

---

Двойки:

```
2222-222+22
2^(22/2)-22-2^2
```

---

Тройки:

```
(333+3+3^(3-3))*(3*3-3)
```

---

Четверки:

```
(444+44+4*4)*4+4+√4
```

Answer (score 8):

2022 единицы:

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 2022
```

Answer (score 8):

семь девяток:

```
(9 * 9 * sqrt(9) - 9 - 9) * 9 - sqrt(9)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
//СЕМЬ ЧЕТВЕРОК
console.log(4 * (4 ** 4 * Math.sqrt(4) - 4 - Math.sqrt(4)) - Math.sqrt(4));
```

Answer (score 6):

Если использовать только арифметические оперции и возвденеие в степень

**Еденицы** (10 шт)

```py
(1 + 1)**11 - (11 + 1 + 1)*(1+1)
```

**Двойки** (8 шт)

```py
2**(22/2) - (22 + 2 + 2)
```

**Тройки** (10 шт)

```py
3 * (3**(3 + 3) - (3**3 + 3**3 + 3/3))
```

Далее решения однотипные, которые включают 11 степень двойки и дальнейшие манипуляции, которые приводят к результату <= 12 цифр

**Четверки** (12 шт)

```py
((4 + 4)/4)**(44/4) - ((44 * 4) / (4 + 4) + 4)
```

**Пятерки** (10 шт)

```py
((5 + 5)/5)**(55/5) - (5 * 5 + 5/5)
```

и т.д.

Поискал совпадения в pi, если интересно кому, то здесь первое попадание

```py
<re.Match object; span=(16335, 16339), match='2022'>
```

**UPD**
Здесь буду добавлять найденные варианты в течении 2022 года

Последовательность 9876543210 (с сохранением порядка)

```py
(9*8*7-6-5)*4 + (3+2)*10
```

Последовательность 0123456789

```py
1023*4 - 5*6*(78-9)
```

Последовательность 01234567

```py
2045 - (5*7 - (6+4+3-1))
```

Последовательность 0123456

```py
2034 - 1 - 5 - 6
```

Answer (score 5):

`"2"+"0"+"2"+"2"`

Comment: `""+2+0+2+2` =)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @eri, `""+2+(2-2)+2+2` ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, `"2"+(2-2)+22`

Comment: @DiD, `2+[2-2]+2+2`

Comment: @eri, смотри, что придумал))

Answer (score 4):

Поскольку новый конкурс заводить не хочется, просто делюсь тем, что накропал для 2023 года на тех же условиях (в этот раз — без битовых операций).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Update**

И как я пропустил такой шедевр?!   **7<sup>7</sup>%7!**

А еще ~(6*6!!)*~6

Comment: Мне кажедся, или 2022 был проще?

Comment: @Mikhailo Ну, я бы не сказал...

Answer (score 2):

насколько я понял в задаче указано **как можно меньшего количества одинаковых цифр**

такой вариант вполне подойдет

```
2022 = 1*2*3*337
```

все просто и нет не одной одинаковой цифры.

и еще как вариант

```py
d = 1 * 2 * 3 * (pow(2, 3)*(pow(2, 3)*5+2)+1)
print(d)
```

Comment: Жаль вас огорчать, но в первом же варианте три одинаковых цифры :)

Comment: есть 1, 2,  3 и 337 и чем же эти цифры одинаковы?

Comment: В **числе** 337 две **цифры** 3

Comment: Похоже, мое профильное *я так стар, что помню те времена, когда программисты знали математику* пора менять на *знали арифметику*... Неужели в начальной школе уже не учат разницу между цифрами и числами? А разницу между словами и буквами?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453059/178988

Comment: @Harry, в примере `1-(1+1)*(1-11111)/11` тоже много одинаковых цифр.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Знаете, есть смешные шутки. Но ваше прикалывание к ним ну никак не относится...

Answer (score 1):

Покажу такой вариант:

```
2*3*337=2022
2^11-26=2022
```