# Новогодний арифметический конкурс 2023

Tags: любой-язык, олимпиада, битовые-операции, арифметика, соревнование

Год назад был объявлен [конкурс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1367394/228791) на представление номера года арифметическими выражениями из цифр. В этом году Harry поспешил все испортить :), опубликовав [свои наработки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1478703/228791) заранее.

Но мы никому не позволим лишить участников ruSO новогоднего раздумья! :) Просто немного изменим правила. В этот раз конкурс — *битовый*.

Задача — представить число 2023 с помощью как можно меньшего количества одинаковых цифр.

Можно использовать скобки, из арифметических операций - только плюс и минус (а также унарный минус), и побитовые операции — И (`&`), ИЛИ (`|`), ИСКЛЮЧАЮЩЕЕ ИЛИ (`^`), ОТРИЦАНИЕ (`~`), сдвиги (`<<` и `>>`).

Еще — то же самое для ряда цифр 1234567890 и 9876543210 - постараться по возможности получить 2023 для всех подпоследовательностей — ну, там, для 1234567, 12345678 и так далее. Ноль не должен быть тривиальным (например, в конце +0)!

Поскольку конкурс чисто развлекательный, пусть победителя определит голосование за ответы. Понятно, что чем меньше цифр использовано — тем круче решение. Но не менее важна и эстетика решения.

А теперь внимание! Мой приз - 250 баллов **плюс все, что будет заработано за счет плюсов этому вопросу**. Так что не забывайте давить на треугольник вверх рядом с ним! :) Приглашаю также поучаствовать спонсоров с наградами понравившимся ответам.

Срок проведения - 10 дней, т.е. окончательные результаты подбиваем после Рождества, 8 января.

PS Допускаю, что здесь могут быть немного разные результаты в разных языках и компиляторах, связанные с размерами типов и т.п. — но здесь вся ответственность на участнике и болельщиках. Считаете, что представление неверное - не голосуйте.

PPS С Новым годом! :) И будьте активнее, активнее! :)

PPPS Осталось несколько дней, и только 4 ответа. И всего 18 голосов на все 4 ответа. Просьба ну хоть немного активнее участвовать/голосовать! Это же не конкурс а курам на смех.

PPPPS Награда по результатам голосования участниками вручена.
Должен сказать прямо, что меня удивляют результаты голосования, но спорить с ними я не могу. 12 плюсов за 7 формальных (проходящих условия конкурса) ответов и 3 вне конкурса, и 9 за 26 формальных и 13 неформальных. Но — не буду спорить, баллы вручены. Но воспользуюсь правом выступить и как спонсор для понравившегося ответа, потому что с точки зрения эстетики в моих глазах внеконкурсный ответ с семерками перекрывает все 26 приведенных формальных ответов. Правда, 350 баллов мне ruSO не позволило дать в награду, только 500 :)

На этом с данным конкурсом я заканчиваю, больше в эти игры я не играю :(

Comment: Предлагаю вырезать `~` из достпных операций, так как чередуя его с минусом можно получить любое число. Например, `console.log(-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~1) // => 9`

Comment: Также предлагаю включить сдвиг `>>>`. Его как-то упустили.

Comment: @DiD Очень классное решение, спасибо! Но менять правила уже, наверное, не стоит. Просто повтор вашего решения - это уже будет плагиат :) Что до `>>>`, то такой сдвиг есть не везде. Я ориентировался в первую очередь на C.

Comment: Меньше цифр у меня уже есть - одна любая для любого числа - вот тут описано: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1367469/178988.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, DiD уже написал. Но это все же читерство...

Comment: @Mikhailo, почему читерство? Всё разрешённое. Надо просто не минимум цифр, а минимум длины или ещё что-то в таком духе.

Comment: *больше в эти игры я не играю* А жаль, здесь так мало развлечений, тем более интеллектуальных :)

Answer (score 19):

Почти зеркальное из восьмерок `8^(-8>>8)+(8<<8)^8+8`.

Или чуть переиграть `(-8<<8^-8>>8)-(8+8+8)`.

Для красоты часть `(8+8+8)` можно заменить, например, `(8^8+8)` или `(8+8|8)`.

С двойками не такое красивое `-(-(2<<-22)|(-2>>>-2)+22)`.

Я уже упомянал в [обсуждении конкурса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12259/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-2023-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0?noredirect=1#comment53044_12259) `9<<999|999`.

Если `9` сдвинуть на `999` разрядов влево, то получаем вместо <strike>`48217887323382029442679127207700081475263216526749012334968767476665797300622125512193927046706313615741760281289891607133421537856154131961930599086143586617705554986709039434394835722780670138450793819688709137426118735703294454016244947757346783115570384149589439754471934242436809740767425506312192`</strike> всего лишь `1152`, что объединяя положительными битами с `999` получаем `2023`:

```
1152  10010000000
 999   1111100111
2023  11111100111
```

Вообще, `999` - число в буквальной степени магически сходится с `2023`.
Как видно, к выражению `x|999` в качестве `x` можно подобрать любое число от `1024` до `2023` при условии, что в значении 4ый и 3ий биты будут отрицательны.

Очень похожее с тройками, но содержит запрещенные умножения  <strike>`33*33|333*3`</strike>.

Тоже похоже, но интересно, и опять умножение <strike>`9<<-9*9*9|999`</strike>.

Вот еще интересное с девятками без умножений `-(-9<<9)^999+(9<<9)`.

Если найдется что-то интересное или симметричное, добавлю.

Я считаю оператор `~` читерским, о чем упомянул в комментариях к вопросу, но я не откажу себе в удовольствии по-пользоваться им:

- `~8^-8<<8^8+8`
- `~-(-2^22^-2<<-22)`
- <strike>`~-(22*22+22<<2)`</strike> (умножение)

Сделал небольшую песочницу для тестов:

```html
<input oninput="out.value=eval(this.value)" value="9<<999|999" /> 
= 
<output id="out">2023</output>
```

Answer (score 15):

Ну, с наступившим

## 7⁷ % 7! годом

Все, все части собраны. Решения с использованием `~` и без него (для DiD). Справа — количество использованных цифр.

```
(1<<11)+~(11<<1)+~1                      = 2023   //  7 digits
(1<<11)-((11+1)<<1)-1                    = 2023   //  8 digits
(2<<(2<<2)<<2)+~22-2                     = 2023   //  7 digits
(22^(((2<<((2<<2)+2+2))-2)>>2))-2        = 2023   // 10 digits
((33&~3)<<(3+3))+~(3<<3)                 = 2023   //  7 digits
((33^((33+3)<<3))<<3)-33                 = 2023   //  9 digits
((((4+4)<<4)-4)<<4)+~4+44                = 2023   //  8 digits
(444>>4)^((((4+4)<<4)<<4)-4)             = 2023   //  9 digits
-~5-~(((5-~5)|55)<<5)                    = 2023   //  6 digits
((55+5+5)<<5)-((55+5)^(5))               = 2023   //  9 digits
(((66|6)+~6)<<(~6+6+6))-~6               = 2023   //  8 digits
(((((6<<6)-6)|(6<<6))<<6)-6)>>(6&(6+6))  = 2023   // 10 digits
((77-7-7)<<(77&7))+7                     = 2023   //  8 digits
~8+~8-8-~(8<<8)                          = 2023   //  5 digits
((((8<<8)<<8)-8)>>8)-8-8-8               = 2023   //  8 digits
(9<<9)^((9<<9)+999)                      = 2023   //  7 digits

~1-23+((4-~5+6)<<7)                      = 2023   //  7 digits
(123<<4)+(56+7)&~8                       = 2023   //  8 digits
(1-234)^((~5-((6|7)<<8))+~9)             = 2023   //  9 digits
(~1-23)^(~4|5)^(((6+7+~8)<<9)+~0)        = 2023   // 10 digits

(9+~(8<<7))^(~(65<<4))                   = 2023   //  6 digits
987+(65<<4)+~3                           = 2023   //  7 digits
987-~(65<<4)-3-2                         = 2023   //  8 digits
~(9<<8)+7+6+~5+4321                      = 2023   //  9 digits
~9+~8+((765|432)<<1)                     = 2023   //  9 digits
~9^(~876&(((54<<3<<2)^~1)+~0))           = 2023   // 10 digits
```

Демонстрация :) — тут: https://ideone.com/jw1IJw

В процессе работы родилось пару достаточно коротких представлений, правда, не подходящих для условий конкурса:

```
(63<<5)+7
(4<<9)-25
```

Второе красиво еще и потому, что 49 и 25 - квадраты...

Вот еще из 4 цифр симметричное: `(4<<9)-(9|4!)`
А вот из трех: `(4<<9)+~(4!)`

Самое красивое (понятно, внеконкурсное) — это **`7⁷ % 7!`**.

И просто со всеми операциями, какие только вспомнил :), получены самые краткие варианты:

```
(1<<11)+~(((~1)*(~1))!)    // 5
~((22<<2)*(~22))           // 5
(~(3!))*~((3!<<3)*3!)      // 4
(4!!<<4!!)+~(4!)           // 3
(~5!*5!!)^(~5!+~5!)        // 4
~(6*6!!)*~6                // 3
7^7%7!                     // 3
(8<<8)+~(sqrt(8+8)!)       // 4
(~9+9!!)|(9!!-~9!!)        // 4
```

Comment: @Mikhailo [Злорадно потирая руки] Ok...

Comment: Какое правило запрещает ответ *2023*? Он короткий - четыре цифры, только три различных.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну, наверное, ответ не должен быть тривиальным?... :) Ладно, вот вам еще красивое — и большие у меня подозрения, что красивее этого для 2023 мы уже не увидим: `7^7 mod 7!`

Comment: @Harry В ответе факториал потерялся. Находка - супер!

Comment: @MBo Спасибо за подсказку. Да, я сам три раза пересчитывал, никак поверить не мог :)

Comment: С такими красивыми семерками год точно должен быть счастливым :)

Answer (score 14):

Ну, если битовый конкурс, то и цифры д.б. двоичные, только 0 и 1.

Поскольку требуется, чтобы все одинаковые, то 0 явно не годится.

А вот из единичек на C/C++:

```
(1 << 11) - ((11 << 1) + (1 << 1) + 1)
```

*это 9 цифр*

Расшифрую в десятичных числах

```
(1 << 11) = 2048
((11 << 1) + (1 << 1) + 1) = 22 + 2 + 1 = 25
2048 - 25 = 2023
```

*Специально для пуристов, которые захотят придраться к десятичному числу 11.

ОК, если только двоичные цифры, то десятичное число 11 вычисляется из двоичных единичек вот так:*

```
((((1 << 1) << 1) << 1) + (1 << 1) + 1)
```

где

```
(((1 << 1) << 1) << 1) = 8
(1 << 1) = 2
```

*если подставлять вместо десятичного 11 это выражение, то результат 19 цифр*

---

А теперь двоичные числа, состоящие только из одинаковых двоичных цифр
*(какая неожиданность, это опять единички)*

```
 11111111111 - 11111 + 111
```

где

```
 111 1111 1111 = 2047
        1 1111 = 31
           111 = 7
 2047 - 31 + 7 = 2023
```

*(к моему удивлению в этом примере тоже оказалось 19 двоичных цифр)*

Answer (score 10):

Много красивых ответов уже есть, мой ответ может быть не так симпотичен, но впервые решил поучаствовать в таком конкурсе.

Основная идея — год получается из деления выражения на возрастающую степень двойки, используются **все цифры** один раз.

```js
console.log((7 | 65 | 934 | 1028)      / 1   )
console.log((9 - 570 + 2 + 4613 - 8)   / 2   )
console.log((8054 + 37 + 1 | 2 & 69)   / 4   )
console.log((8 - 723 - 5 + 16904)      / 8   )
console.log((8091 + 2 << 34 ^ 5 & 76)  / 16  )
console.log((3 - 801 - 2 & 64759)      / 32  )
console.log((51 << 70 ^ 432 + 69 << 8) / 64  )
console.log((1035782 >> 6 << ~4 + 9)   / 128 )
console.log((3 - 68 + 2 & 517940)      / 256 )
```

Варианты с единицами и 2023

```js
console.log(111+1111|1111-1-111) 
console.log((1^111>>1<<1-111) / ((111>>1<<1-111^1) / 2023))
```

Вариант с двойками (убывающий размер групп):

```js
console.log(2222-222-~22)
```

Вариант с 3 и 4 (связь между 1991 и 2023)

```js
console.log(343 + 44 | 433 << 34)
console.log(343 + 44 | 433 << 34 ^ 34)
```

Вариант с группами (5, 6) и (7, 8)

```js
console.log(5 + 56 << 6565 | 65 + 6)
console.log(8 << 7 | 8787 - 7788)
```

Девятки:

```js
console.log( 999 | 999999 >> 9 )
console.log( 9 << 999 | 999 | 999 )
```

Answer (score 6):

а пример вообще без цифр и каких-либо операций привести можно? ну, например, с помощью языка posix-совместимого shell-а:

```
$ x=;xx=xx;xxx=xxx;echo ${#xx}${#x}${#xx}${#xxx}
2023
```

---

по-моему, вышеприведённое решение вполне себе удовлетворяет условиям конкурса: язык программирования таки используется.

вот вам для контраста явно вне-конкурсное:

```
$ date +%Y -dnext\ year
2023
```

Comment: Можно. Но это уже вне конкурса :)

Comment: @Mikhailo дополнил ответ иллюстрацией того, что лежит явно вне конкурса.

Comment: ну. в base64 показать :)

Comment: Круто, вот что значит  просто мыслить иначе

Answer (score 3):

## Варианты для JS

Получаем 1 и складываем 2023 раза:

- `+[]` - это 0
- `!+[]` - это `!0` - это `true`
- `+!+[]` - это `+true` - это `1`

```js
console.log(+!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[]);
```

Получаем 2023 как строчку и приводим к числовому типу

- `[] + number` - это `'number'`
- `+'number'` - это `number`

```js
console.log(+([] + (+!+[] + +!+[]) + (+[]) + (+!+[] + +!+[]) + (+!+[] + +!+[] + +!+[])));
```

Тут ответ не число, а строка на английском, но всё равно прикольную вещь придумал:

```js
const _0 = +[];
const _1 = +!_0;
const _2 = _1 + _1;
const _4 = _2 + _2;
const _8 = _4 + _4;
const _16 = _8 + _8;
const _32 = _16 + _16;

const _objectObject = [] + {}; // Тут [object Object]
const _undefined = [] + [][_0];
const _NaN = [] + +_undefined;
const _false = [] + ![];
const _true = [] + !![];

const a = _NaN[_1];
const c = _objectObject[_4 + _1];
const d = _undefined[_2];
const e = _undefined[_2 + _1];
const i = _undefined[_4 + _1];
const l = _false[_2];
const n = _undefined[_1];
const o = _objectObject[_1];
const r = _true[_1];
const s = _false[_2 + _1];
const t = _objectObject[_4 + _2];
const u = _undefined[_0];

const _space = _objectObject[_4 + _2 + _1];
const _constructor = c+o+n+s+t+r+u+c+t+o+r;
const _slice = s+l+i+c+e;
const _String = ([] + ([]+[])[_constructor])[_slice](_8 + _1, _8 + _4 + _2 + _1);
const _toString = t+o+_String;

const _35 = _32 + _2 + _1;

const h = (_16 + _1)[_toString](_35);
const w = (_32)[_toString](_35);
const y = (_32 + _2)[_toString](_35);

console.log(t+w+o + _space + t+h+o+u+s+a+n+d + _space + t+w+e+n+t+y + _space + t+h+r+e+e);
```

Хардкорная версия предыдущего варианта:

```js
console.log(([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+((+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])))[([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))]+([]+![])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+!![])[(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+[])]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))]+([]+!![])[(+!(+[]))]])[([]+![])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+![])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]]((+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])),(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])))]((+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])))+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+((+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])))[([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))]+([]+![])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+!![])[(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+[])]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))]+([]+!![])[(+!(+[]))]])[([]+![])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+![])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]]((+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])),(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])))]((+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])))+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+[])]+([]+![])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+ +([]+[][(+[])]))[(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+((+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])))[([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))]+([]+![])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+!![])[(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+[])]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))]+([]+!![])[(+!(+[]))]])[([]+![])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+![])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]]((+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])),(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])))]((+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])))+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+((+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])))[([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))]+([]+![])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+!![])[(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+[])]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))]+([]+!![])[(+!(+[]))]])[([]+![])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+![])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]]((+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])),(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])))]((+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])))+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+((+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])))[([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))]+([]+![])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+!![])[(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+[])]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))]+([]+!![])[(+!(+[]))]])[([]+![])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+![])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+{})[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]]((+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])),(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])))]((+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[])))+([]+!![])[(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]+([]+[][(+[])])[(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))+(+!(+[]))]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Внесу свои 5 копеек. Нижеприведенный код - это валидный javascript. Если запустить его в консоли браузера (или в node), то на выходе в консоли получим `2023`

```js
_=~[];_={___:++_,$$$$:(![]+"")[_],__$:++_,$_$_:(![]+"")[_],_$_:++_,$_$$:({}+"")[_],$$_$:(_[_]+"")[_],_$$:++_,$$$_:(!""+"")[_],$__:++_,$_$:++_,$$__:({}+"")[_],$$_:++_,$$$:++_,$___:++_,$__$:++_};_.$_=(_.$_=_+"")[_.$_$]+(_._$=_.$_[_.__$])+(_.$$=(_.$+"")[_.__$])+((!_)+"")[_._$$]+(_.__=_.$_[_.$$_])+(_.$=(!""+"")[_.__$])+(_._=(!""+"")[_._$_])+_.$_[_.$_$]+_.__+_._$+_.$;_.$$=_.$+(!""+"")[_._$$]+_.__+_._+_.$+_.$$;_.$=(_.___)[_.$_][_.$_];_.$(_.$(_.$$+"\""+_.$$__+_._$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$_$+_.$$_+"\\"+_.__$+_.$$_+_._$$+_._$+(![]+"")[_._$_]+_.$$$_+"."+(![]+"")[_._$_]+_._$+"\\"+_.__$+_.$__+_.$$$+"("+_._$_+_.___+_._$_+_._$$+")"+"\"")())();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут нет ни одной цифры, но я не уверен, что это решение полностью удовлетворяет условиям конкурса, поскольку используются неоговоренные символы

**PS**: получен с помощью [этого](https://utf-8.jp/public/jjencode.html) обфускатора

Answer (score 0):

Хотя конкурс давно закончился, но почему-бы и не устроить безумие из следующих символов в JavaScript: `(+![]<)`?

```js
((+!![]+!![])<<(+!![]+!![])<<(+!![]+!![])<<(+!![]+!![])<<(+!![]+!![])<<(+!![]+!![]))-(((!+[])+!+[])<<((!+[])+(!+[])))-(((!+[])+!+[])<<((!+[])+(!+[])))-(((!+[])+!+[])<<((!+[])+(!+[])))-(+!![])
```