# Как в C++ прочитать файл в шестнадцатеричном режиме?

Tags: c++, строки, файлы, hex

Нужно на C++ сделать вот что: открыть файл, как если бы его открыли в шестнадцатеричном редакторе, дойти до строки 00000030, при длине строки 16 символов, и вывести hex-содержимое этой строки на экран. Причём именно в hex, никак не в строковом виде!

---

Harry, хз, я пробовал так:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("file.bin", ios::binary);
    string tmpl;
    while(getline(myfile, tmpl)) {
        cout << hex << tmpl << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Читаете побайтово, выводите в шестнадцатеричном виде, в чем проблема? Через `cout` — читайте о `hex`, через `printf` - о `%X`...

Comment: `string tmpl; ifstream fileo; fileo.open("file.bin", ios::in); while (getline(fileo, tmpl)) { cout << hex << tmpl << endl; };`. Вот так?

Comment: прочитал. Там через hex выводится число. А мне надо строку/бинарные данные прогнать

Comment: Нет, конечно... Открывайте как бинарный а не текстовый. Если нужна только строка 00030 (это число шестнадцатеричное или десятичное?), становитесь на нужную позицию в файле (`seekg()`), и читаете 16 байт. Потом выводите. Или в цикле 16 раз по 1 байту.

Comment: *Там через hex выводится число. А мне надо строку/бинарные данные прогнать* Как все запущено... В памяти, в файле нет строк или символов или чисел... Все упирается в вопрос, как именно трактовать набор байтов :)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1413657/478514

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конкретно с чтением в hex разобрался.

```
ifstream binfile;
binfile.open("file.bin", ios::binary);
char ipc;
while(binfile.get(ipc)) {
    cout << hex << (int)ipc;
}
```

binfile.get - чтение по байтам. (int)ipc - перевод char в int.

Comment: Конкретно в вашей задаче строка - это 16 байт. Вам нужно сначала пропустить `(0x30-1) * 16` байт, а потом считать 16 байт и вывести на экран в шестнадцатеричном формате.

Comment: Неправильно. Ширину вывода не выставил.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например, так. Только убедитесь, что файл достаточной длины :)

```
int main()
{
    ifstream in("data",ios::binary);
    if (!in.is_open()) { cerr << "Error open file\n"; return 1; }
    if (!in.seekg(0x30*16)) { cerr << "Error seek file\n"; return 1; }
    unsigned char buf[16];
    if (!in.read((char*)buf,16)) { cerr << "Error read file\n"; return 1; }
    cout << hex << setfill('0');
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
        cout << setw(2) << (unsigned int)buf[i] << ' ';

}
```

Comment: ответ отличный, но только я думаю, что все таки `in.seekg(0x30)`, не нужно умножать на 16. Но может у автора вопроса особый hex редактор.

Comment: @KoVadim У него 0x30 - номер строки, где каждая строка по 16 байт...

Comment: Зная хекс редакторы, Я сомневаюсь

Comment: я через xxd дампал

Comment: Если так, то похоже я прав

Comment: @KoVadim Ну... я исходил из *дойти до строки 00000030, при длине строки 16 символов*. Конечно, если  это смещение, то умножение на 16 не нужно... Но тогда надо подправить сам вопрос.

Comment: Видимо я больше с хекс редакторами работал