# Как проверить, что число не существует в какой то системе счисления?

Tags: c#, pascal, pascalabc.net

> C клавиатуры вводится число. Вывести все системы счисления,  в
> которых данное число не существует.

Как такое решать?

Comment: Вы какие системы счисления знаете?

Comment: 2,3,8,10. Также 16. Слышал про 20 и 60 системы. Но надо в задание до 10 включительно системы (2,3,8,10). @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: Придумайте какое-нибудь десятичное число, но чтобы он не было двоичным. Подумайте над общим принципом.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy стоит тогда поставить на проверку к какой системе относится да?

Comment: Почему `123` не годится в качестве двоичного числа? Хотя может быть десятичным.

Comment: 123 не подходит к двоичной так как есть числа 2 и 3 @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: Тогда ваша задача глядя на цифры числа решить какие системы счисления не подходят.

Comment: а то есть тут надо проверять по цифрам. Если вот 123 , то системы которые не входят это 2 и 3 системы счисления. Так? @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: Приблизительно так.

Comment: все очень просто цифры, буквы должны быть меньше системы счисления иначе не подходит допустим для 16 ричной не подхотит `5G` хотя для интернета годится)), пример на десятеричной `9` < 10, пример для двоичной  `1` < 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так в итоге получается:

```
var 
  number: integer;
  digit, max, i: integer;
  
begin
  max := 1;
  write('Введите число: ');
  readln(number);
  number := abs(number);
  while number <> 0 do 
  begin
    digit := number mod 10;
    if digit > max then 
      max := digit;
    number := number div 10;
  end;
  writeln('Недопустимые системы счисления:');
  if max < 2 then
    writeln('Отсутствуют.');
  for i := 2 to max do
    write(i, ' ');
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##NYvNCoJAGEX3PcXgagQbTCsLKSiz0jJL@9@ZftlQjuYY1NPbEAR3cbicE/NmzGldvzhlKQo/vIKMLCl7mo2GlTOeP4AcSlqB@ACHVSk04uaUYUlBYjZ7ZVBGF6EFEUsBqwr6dwFEyS@TyTbfFQWUgrzojeMbGgyRpLY0vd3pGr3@aGxN7Ols7riLpbfy15sg3O72h@PpLBGHJfD2ryKSZZmEd1pgTZBZ10ZP/wI)

```
using System.Linq;

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(1, Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().Max(ch => "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".IndexOf(ch))).Skip(1)));
```

```
783
```

```
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

> Надо именно чтобы было число в типе данных integer.

```
Console.WriteLine
(
  x == 0
    ? "Запись нуля в единичной системе счисления в виде пустой строки сомнительна")
    : "Число {0} можно представить в любой системе счисления с положительным основанием",
  x
);
```

Comment: прошу прощения, но это не так. Надо именно чтобы было число в типе данных integer. И работать с string нельзя @Qwertiy

Comment: @KaneJons, Логика проста: находите максимальную цифру в этом числе и ответом будут все системы счисления, с основанием от 2 до этой цифры включительно.

Comment: @KaneJons, во-первых, ты в вопросе написал: "C клавиатуры вводится число". Во-вторых, [integer существует независимо от систем счисления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988), а значит нет такой системы, в которой он не представим (за исключением экзотических типа основания 0).

Comment: @Alekcvp, и почему же?

Comment: @Qwertiy Потому что, если говорить о позиционных системах счисления, основание системы счисления равно количество цифр в ней. Соответственно, в восьмеричной - это 8, максимальная 7. В двоичной - это 2, максимальная 1. И т.п. Т.к. автор вопроса указал что речь идёт об Integer, то основания выше 10 быть не может, иначе для записи потребуются буквы, а их в Integer не запишешь.

Comment: @Alekcvp, в integer и цифры не запишешь - там только биты.

Comment: @Qwertiy, В Integer записывается целое число. По странному стечению обстоятельств, любое число в системе с основанием меньше 10 можно записать туда как десятичное и анализировать его. Например: (8)367 - можно ввести как десятичное 367 и анализировать каждый разряд. (2)110011 можно ввести как десятичное 110011 и так же анализировать каждый разряд. И т.п. Как именно там хранятся эти числа - значения не имеет.

Comment: @Alekcvp, а какое отношение десятичная система имеет к integer?

Comment: @Alekcvp система счисления - представление числа, а не само число. Не пишите ерунду.

Comment: @aepot, а вы условия задачи читали? Для её решения Integer достаточно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, написал как это делается через Integer, см. ответ.

Comment: @Alekcvp читал, оно не имеет никакого смысла. Систем счисления бесконечное множество.

Comment: @Alekcvp, это нелогично.

Comment: @aepot, условие задачи ограничивает выборку только 9ю первыми, если там действительно запрещено использовать строки для решения. В противном случае задача вообще не имеет решения.