# Не выводятся ведущие нули

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, list

Почему при выводе списка строк в номерах, которые начинаются с нуля, не выводятся сами нули?

```
import re

def sanitize_phone_number(phone):
    phone_numbers = [re.sub('\D', '', digi)
                     for digi in [phone_number
                     for phone_number in phone]]
    phone_numbers = [int(phone_number) for phone_number in phone_numbers]
    print(phone_numbers)
    return phone_numbers

phones = ["    +38(050)123-32-34",
    "     0503451234",
    "(050)8889900",
    "38050-111-22-22",
    "38050 111 22 11   "]
sanitize_phone_number(phones)
```

Проблема вроде в 7-ой строке. Подскажите, как её исправить?

Comment: Не int. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что в этой строке

```
phone_numbers = [int(phone_number) for phone_number in phone_numbers]
```

Вы из списка строк делаете список чисел типа `int`, этот тип данных не сохраняет ведущие нули.

Если просто закомментировать данную строку, то вывод будет с ведущими нулями:

```
['380501233234', '0503451234', '0508889900', '380501112222', '380501112211']
```

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, а как тогда я могу распаковать их?

Comment: @Pain что значит распаковать? У вас уже без этой строки в переменной `phone_numbers` находится список строк с телефонами

Comment: Они же в типе строки, а я хотел бы сделать список с чисел (int'овые)

Comment: @Pain а зачем? Стандартная практика номера телефонов хранить в виде строк, если всё таки хотите инты, то придётся отказаться от ведущих нулей