# Как подсчитать количество цифр в файле txt?

Tags: c++, файлы

Я уже пытался что-то реализовать, но безуспешно. В файле текст + цифры. Мне нужно подсчитать именно количество цифр

Вот мой код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
   {
   int num;
   int k = 0;
   ifstream file("open1.txt");
   //string str;
   if (!file)
      {
      cout << " file is not found" << endl;
      exit(1);
    }
   while (file >> num)
      {
            k++;    
   }
   cout << "Number in file:" << k << endl;
   file.close();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Цифр или чисел?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453059/178988

Answer (score 4):

Если *именно цифр* то вполне достаточно четырех строк:

```
ifstream file("open1.txt");
int k = 0;
for(char c; file>>c; k += isdigit(c)!=0);
cout << k;
```

Если файл не открылся, выведет 0.

Если вы хотите что-то делать с ними - что именно, непонятно, **ПОЛУЧИТЬ В КОНСОЛЬ** это что-то странное... - то

```
ifstream file("open1.txt");
int k = 0;
for(char c; file>>c; ) {
    if (isdigit(c)) {
        ++k;
        // Тут вы ПОЛУЧАЕТЕ В КОНСОЛЬ символ с
        }
    };
cout << k;
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь спасибо за ответ он правильный но мне эти цифры (только цифры) необходимо получить из файла в консоль что бы Я мог потом з ними работать к примеру: получения количества положительных и отрицательных цифр, количество парных и не парных, какая цифра самая большая а какая самая маленькая и перезаписи этих цифр в другой файл к примеру.

Comment: Давайте по-честному: вы написали **Мне нужно подсчитать именно количество цифр**. Вы понимаете, что то, что вы сейчас написали - это ДРУГАЯ задача? И за то, что это ВЫ написали условие неверно, мне ставите минус?

Comment: @Nazar отрицательных цифр не бывает. Да и положительных цифр в общем-то тоже; цифры — это просто знаки, из которых составляются числа

Comment: @andreymal, ну вообще я могу создать систему счисления с цифрами `-1`, `0` и `+1`.

Comment: `char c; ... isdigit(c)` — [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
/*подключим функцию isdigit()*/
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int k = 0;

ifstream file("input.txt");


//если файл открылся
if(file.is_open()){
char mychar; /*переменная буфер для посимвольного чтения*/
while (file)
{
    mychar = file.get();
    if(isdigit(mychar)){  /*если считанный символ - цифра, увеличим счётчик*/
            k++;
        }

}
}

cout << "Number in file:" << k << endl;

file.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `isdigit(mychar)` -> `isdigit((unsigned char)mychar)`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit

Comment: Я извиняюсь спасибо за ответ он правильный но мне эти цифры (только цифры) необходимо получить из файла в консоль что бы Я мог  потом з ними работать к примеру: получения количества положительных и отрицательных цифр, количество парных и не парных, какая цифра самая большая а какая самая маленькая и перезаписи этих цифр в другой файл к примеру.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, тут история даже более запутанная. Во-первых цикл чтения организован неверно. Сперва считываем символ `file.get()`, обрабатываем его и только потом, на следующей итерации цикла проверяем, а что мы там вообще говоря считали `while (file)`. Во-вторых, вызов `get()` возвращает значение типа `std::ifstream::int_type`. Функция отображения из `char` в `std::ifstream::int_type` и обратно определяется реализацией. Не гарантируется, что преобразование с помощью простого приведения типа (`char mychar = file.get();`) даст корректный результат.

Comment: Нужно использовать специальную функцию [`char mychar = std::ifstream::traits_type::to_char_type( file.get() );`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/to_char_type). (Либо использовать перегруженную версию функции `get`, которая принимает объект типа `char` по ссылке: `file.get(mychar)`.) И только потом приводить к `unsigned char`: `isdigit((unsigned char)mychar)`.

Comment: Задача явно уровня школы/1 курса универа (нулевых годов, сейчас незнаю), поэтому, имхо, мой вариант вполне рабочий (цифры он считает - а перегрузка, трейты и т.д. это уже уровень повыше. Другое дело, как действительно стоит задача? Чего хочет "заказчик"? Судя по всему, "заказчику" надо разобраться с терминами и правильно задать вопрос. (И скорее всего либо задача будет примерно такая-же по простоте, либо вылезут подводные камни и необходимость работать с памятью/динамическими массивами и т.д.)