Как в js можно можно получить массив чисел от 000000 до 999999, но он должет иметь вид 000001, 000002 и т.д.?
Как в js можно можно получить массив чисел от 000000 до 999999, но он должет иметь вид 000001, 000002 и т.д.?

Числа не могут иметь такой вид. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros

строки с strpad

Используем для вывода данных padStart.
Пример:


let startNumber = 1;
let endNumber = 999;
let strLength = 6;
let padSymbol = '0';

for (let i = startNumber; i <= endNumber; ++i) {
    document.body.innerHTML += (i.toString().padStart(strLength, padSymbol) + "<br>");
}




Благодарю Вас. Это то, что мне нужно.

@ArturAlex Отметье ответ принятым, пожалуйста
